# What's the simplest way to strip trailing whitespace from all lines in a file?

Tags: whitespace, line-breaks

It's pretty common when programming or opening text files to encounter files with trailing whitespace at the end of a line. vim has a way to show this by setting the `trail` option in the `listchars` option and then turning `list` on.

However, what's the easiest way to eliminate that trailing whitespace globally across the whole of a file (ideally without a plugin)?

Comment: The corresponding Stack Overflow question is *[How to remove trailing white spaces using a regular expression without removing empty lines (code cleaning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532340)*.

Comment: Here is a [doc entry](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces) on topic.

Comment: If you have installed [vim-faq](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim_faq), you can get an offline answer there: `:h vim-faq` and search `/trailing`. The hard to memorize tag is [`:h faq-12.1`](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-12.1).

Comment: A lot of complicated answers below, for me `:g/ $/norm $diw` seems to do the job. This moves to the end of lines that end with a whitespace and "deletes inside word". Tabs and spaces appear to be considered as a single word, so as long as there is at least one trailing space this does the trick. I may be missing some cases though?

Comment: `:g/\s$/norm $diw` appears to deal with other whitespace characters as well.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

### Use a keybinding to strip all trailing whitespace

Since some pages that I edit actually need trailing whitespaces (e.g. markdown) and others don't, I set up a keybinding to <kbd>F5</kbd> so that it's trivial to do without being automatic. To do so, add the [code below (from vim.wikia)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces#Simple_commands_to_remove_unwanted_whitespace) or some variation of it to your `.vimrc`:

```
"Remove all trailing whitespace by pressing F5
nnoremap <F5> :let _s=@/<Bar>:%s/\s\+$//e<Bar>:let @/=_s<Bar><CR>
```

- `nnoremap <F5>` does a nonrecursive mapping to the key `F5` in normal mode
- `:let _s=@/` stores the last search term (from the macro `@/`) in the variable `_s`
- `<Bar>` Functions as a pipe symbol `|` to separate commands, however `|` would end a command in this context, so `<Bar>` must be used instead.
- `:%s/\s\+$//e` searches for trailing whitespace and deletes it everywhere in the buffer (see [CarpetSmoker's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/456/1111) for a detailed breakdown of this expression)
- `let @/=_s` restores your last search term to the macro `@/`, so that it will be available the next time you hit `n`.
- `<CR>` ends the mapping

---

### ... or be more selective

If you have cases in which you don't want to strip all of the trailing whitespace, you can use a pattern to be more selective. For example, the following code shows how I strip trailing whitespace only if it comes after a semicolon (here it's tied to <kbd>F8</kbd>).

```
nnoremap <F8> :let _s=@/<Bar>:%s/;\s\+$/;/e<Bar>:let @/=_s<Bar><CR>
```

This is useful if, like me, you have some files with markdown-like [heredocs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) interspersed among semicolon-terminated programming statements.

Comment: Try `:keeppatterns` to prevent overriding `@/`. And also take a look at `:keepjumps`.

Comment: @Bohr What version of vim are you using? I tried `:help keeppattern` and didn't get anything.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms At least version [7.4.155](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/README).

Comment: @Bohr. Thanks! Come to find out I was still using 7.4.0. I installed the latest version and it's available.

Comment: You can get the same effect by wrapping this command in a function, since then the last search term is automatically restored :-) This way you don't have to muck about with `:nohl` either, if if you were highlighting something, it will keep highlighting it (see my updated answer).

Comment: `:nohl` seems redundant to me - there are no trailing spaces which will be highlighted. Perhaps the previous values of `hl` should be restored? Not just set off.

Comment: @jalanb Thanks! I tried it out and it seemed to work fine without it, so I removed it in the code above.

Comment: Keep in mind that `:keeppatterns` showed up at some point after 7.4 was released so if you work on multiple machines with differing versions of Vim, you'll need to use `if exists(':keeppatterns')` before using it. (I suspect the restoration of the previous search pattern showed up after release as well, otherwise I wouldn't have it in my vimrc.)

Comment: why would a markdown page require trailing whitespace?

Comment: @baxx To keep lines from running together.

Answer (score 305):

The "simplest" way is to just use `:substitute`:

```
:%s/\s\+$//e
```

- `:%s` to run `:substitute` over the range `%`, which is the entire buffer.
- `\s` to match all whitespace characters.
- `\+` to match 1 or more of them.
- `$` to anchor at the end of the line.
- The `e` flag to not give an error if there is no match (i.e. the file is already without trailing whitespace).

However, this is probably not the "best" way as it causes two side-effects:

1. it moves the cursor to the last match;
2. it adds the command to the history and search history;
3. it resets the last search term.

You can fix this with a small function:

```
fun! TrimWhitespace()
    let l:save = winsaveview()
    keeppatterns %s/\s\+$//e
    call winrestview(l:save)
endfun
```

And then use it like:

```
:call TrimWhitespace()
```

1. The `winsaveview()` will save the current "view", which includes the cursor position, folds, jumps, etc. The `winrestview()` at the end will restore this from the saved variable.
2. The `:keeppatterns` prevents the `\s\+$` pattern from being added to the search history.
3. The last-used search term is automatically restored after leaving a function, so we don't have to do anything else for this.

Since this is somewhat annoying to type `:call` all the time, you can define a command:

```
command! TrimWhitespace call TrimWhitespace()
```

Which can be be used without the `:call`:

```
:TrimWhitespace
```

And you can of course bind it to a key:

```
:noremap <Leader>w :call TrimWhitespace()<CR>
```

---

Some people like to automatically do this before they write a file to disk, like so:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * call TrimWhitespace()
```

I don't like it, as some formats require trailing whitespace (such as  [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p)), and on some other occasions you even want trailing whitespace in your code (such as formatting an email, and using the `--<Space>` marker to indicate the start of a signature).

You can skip binary files with:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * if !&binary | call TrimWhitespace() | endif
```

Or other filestypes:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * if !&binary && &ft !=# 'mail' 
                   \|   call TrimWhitespace()
                   \| endif
```

---

Shameless plug mode: a while ago I [wrote a little Python script](http://code.arp242.net/sanitize_files) to clean up whitespace for an entire project at once.

Comment: If you don't want to create a function to move to the previous position you could just press ``​`​`` twice after the replace is finished.

This opens the possibility to create a oneliner like this:
```%s/\s\+$//e | exe "normal ``"```

Comment: @NeaţuOvidiuGabriel, of course then the double backtick will not work the same after the oneliner is executed.  ;)

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1618401. But I like Martin's code more.

Comment: I do it the same way: 
:%s/\s\+$//e
and before I convert Tabs to spaces:
:%retab

Comment: FWIW matching zero or more `*` is the same as `\+` like so `:s/\s*$//e`

Answer (score 21):

To delete all trailing whitespace (at the end of each line), you can use the command:

```
:%s/ \+$//
```

To include tabs, use `\s` instead of space.

---

From the command-line:

```
$ ex +'%s/\s\+$//e' -cwq file.c
```

All the files in the current directory (recursively use `**/*.*`):

```
$ ex +'bufdo!%s/\s\+$//e' -cxa *.*
```

---

Python way:

```
:py import vim
:pydo vim.current.buffer[linenr - 1] = vim.current.buffer[linenr - 1].strip()
```

or:

```
:py import vim
:py for i, l in enumerate(vim.current.buffer): vim.current.buffer[i] = l.rstrip()
```

<sup>Use `lstrip()` for left strip (trailing), `rstrip()` for right strip (leading) or `strip()` to remove from both ends.</sup>

---

Here is useful function which removes superfluous white space from the end of a line which you can add to your `.vimrc`:

```
" Removes superfluous white space from the end of a line
function! RemoveWhiteSpace()
   :%s/\s*$//g
    :'^
    "`.
endfunction
```

---

There is also [DeleteTrailingWhitespace](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967) plugin for that.

---

**Highlighting white spaces**

To double-check if all trailing spaces are gone, use:

1. Type `/ $` to find them. If there are some, vim would highlight them for you.
2. Use colours to highlight them:

   ```
   :highlight ws ctermbg=red guibg=red
   :match ws /\s\+$/
   ```
3. Use visible characters ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299952/55075)):

   ```
   :set encoding=utf-8
   :set listchars=trail:·
   :set list
   ```

See also: [Highlight unwanted spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip396)

To highlight trailing whitespace by default, you may configure your `.vimrc` as follow:

```
highlight ws ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ws /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ws /\s\+$/
```

---

**Removing white spaces by default**

If you would like to make sure that all trailing whitespace in a file are removed automatically on save, you may add the following command into your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.c,*.php :%s/\s\+$//ge
```

which may not be recommended, as it'll unconditionally strip trailing whitespace from every file of that type saved by an user saves and there's not a good way to prevent that where trailing whitespace might be desired (which should be rare, but still.)

---

See also:

- [Remove unwanted spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces) at vim wikia
- [How to trim whitespace (including tabs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs) at stackoverflow
- [How can you automatically remove trailing whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356126/how-can-you-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-vim) at stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

Exapnding on [Christopher Bottoms's answer a bit](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/454/whats-the-simplest-way-to-strip-trailing-whitespace-from-all-lines-in-a-file/2285#2285): Jonathan Palardy [wrote a good article on this](https://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/preserve-a-vim-function-that-keeps-your-state/). In it, he writes a functions, `Preserve(command)`, that preserves the state of the editor (mainly cursor position and last search pattern) while running an arbitrary command:

```
function! Preserve(command)
  " Preparation: save window state
  let l:saved_winview = winsaveview()
  " Run the command:
  execute a:command
  " Clean up: restore previous window position
  call winrestview(l:saved_winview)
endfunction
```

This has the advantage being multipurpose, for example you can use it to replace all trailing whitespace (as Jonathan does) by mapping this to :

```
nnoremap <F5> :call Preserve("%s/\\s\\+$//e")<CR>
```

You can also use it for a visual mode mapping to just remove the trailing spaces on visually selected lines:

```
xnoremap <F5> :call Preserve("'<,'>s/\\s\\+$//e")<CR>
```

And you can use it for other calls, like formatting the whole document using `=` while retaining your place (well use a different key this time so as not to conflict):

```
nnoremap <F6> :call Preserve("normal gg=G")<CR>
```

All and all, I've found the `Preserve(command)` function to be a nice tool to have.

Comment: The last used search term should be automatically preserved when you leave a function; so mucking about with `@/` should not be required (in this case, anyway).

Comment: `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()` are far superior.

Comment: Quite right! Updated based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Another version of the StripTrailingSpaces function:

```
if !exists('*StripTrailingWhitespace')
    function! StripTrailingWhitespace() range
        if !&binary && &filetype != 'diff'
            call Preserve(":" . a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . "s/\\s\\+$//e")
        endif
    endfunction
endif

" http://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/preserve-a-vim-function-that-keeps-your-state/
if !exists('*Preserve')
    function! Preserve(command)
        try
            let l:win_view = winsaveview()
             "silent! keepjumps keeppatterns execute a:command
            silent! execute 'keeppatterns keepjumps ' . a:command
        finally
            call winrestview(l:win_view)
        endtry
    endfunction
endif
```

*Actually there is a bug in this function* (this one):

The position is not being kept because of the "range" option.
It it is removed, and it works very well. However, I am sharing the code to receive some help.

As you can see, it also uses the **Preserve** function seen above, but in a slightly different fashion.

The difference here is that I can select a range of lines or a paragraph with `vip` and then the range `:'<,'>` will automatically appear
at the command prompt.

The idea came from [a Bez Hermoso post](https://bezhermoso.github.io/til/vim-function-ranges/).

Comment: Re *"I am sharing the code to receive some help"*: Are you asking a question?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long giving you feedback. The needed "Preserve" function was finally added. Now my answer makes some sense. It is an attempt to make getting rid of trailing spaces easier.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to all the previous answers. I really like the use of `keeppatterns`. I just want to add one more thing that no one else mentioned - the `substitute` command's confirmation flag. This could effectively handle the case where certain filetypes, or even specific lines in a file, shouldn't have trailing spaces removed. Here it is as an autocommand...

```
autocmd BufWritePre * let [v,c,l]=[winsaveview(),&cuc,&cul]
                  \ | set cuc cul
                  \ | keeppatterns %s/\s\+$//ec
                  \ | let [&cuc,&cul]=[c,l]
                  \ | call winrestview(v)
                  \ | unlet v l c
```

Explanation:

1. Save the current window/cursor state, and the values of the `cursorcolumn` and `cursorline` settings.
2. Turn on `cursorcolumn` and `cursorline` to make the next step easier to follow.
3. Remove all trailing whitespace. The `c` flag at the end moves the cursor to each occurrence and asks for confirmation: `replace with  (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)?`
4. Restore the `cursorcolumn` and `cursorline` settings to what they were beforehand.
5. Restore the window/cursor state.
6. Dump the variables we don't need anymore.

Comment: If you put the code in a function, it's easier to format _and_ you can use `l:` variables so that you don't have to `:unlet` them