# How to debug a mapping?

Tags: key-bindings

I see a lot of questions on here where a user has a mapping which doesn't work
and most of the time the reasons are pretty similar.

I suggest to make this question a reference for this kind of questions, to give a complete procedure to debug a mapping. If a user as a problem with
a mapping they could be redirected here to eliminate the most common issues.

Of course there will still be particular cases which will require a dedicated
question and will not be addressed here.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Your mapping doesn't do what it should do or behaves differently than expected, several steps are to follow to troubleshoot that:

### Check that the key is effectively mapped to what it should do

Vim provides a command `:map`. By default, (when no argument is given) the
command will show all the mappings currently created. Here is an example of
the result of the command:

[image: result of :map]

As always the doc is your friend: [`:h map-listing`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map%2Dlisting)

You can see in the first column the mode of the mapping (`n` for normal mode,
`v` for visual mode, etc), the second column shows the keys mapped and the
last column what the keys are mapped to.
Note that before the mapped actions some additional characters may appear, it
is important to understand them:

- `*`  indicates that it is not remappable (i.e., it is not a recursive mapping, see `know when to use nore` later in this answer)
- `&`  indicates that only script-local mappings are re-mappable
- `@`  indicates a buffer-local mapping

When asking for help about a mapping it is a good thing to add this
information since it can help other people to understand the behavior of your mapping.

It is possible to restrict the prompt to a particular mode with the sister-commands
of `:map`, like `:vmap`, `:nmap`, `:omap`, etc.

Now to restrict your search to the problematic mapping you can pass the key
sequence you're debugging as the parameter of the commands, like this:

```
:map j
:map <Leader>m
:map <F5>
```

Note that the `<Leader>` key will be replaced by its actual value in the list.

If the result of the command shows that your keys are correctly mapped, it probably
means that the problem doesn't come from Vim but from your terminal or your desktop
environment. See the part **Check if your mapping is actually intercepted by Vim**

If the result of the command shows that your keys are not correctly mapped see the
following part.

### Check what overrode your mapping

Another convenient use of the `:map` command is to combine it with `verbose`:
This will prompt the last file which modified your mapping.

For example, see these two screenshots which are the results of `:verbose map`: the first one is a mapping modified by
my `.vimrc` and the second a mapping created by a plugin:

[image: Mapping set from vimrc]

[image: Mapping set from a plugin]

Now if you see that another script modified your mapping you'll have to see if
you can remove it or modify its behavior. *(Note that some plugins provide
variable to enable/disable their mappings, unfortunately not all of the plugins
do that)*

If the last file which changed your mapping is your `.vimrc`, make sure there is no other line that also defines a mapping for the same key. The `.vimrc` file will happily override any mappings with the last one of its kind in the file.

## Check if your mapping is actually intercepted by Vim

Several situations may indicate that Vim doesn't intercept your key:

- The command `:map` shows that your key is correctly mapped but pressing it does nothing.
- Your mapping works on gVim (GUI) but does nothing in terminal Vim
- Your mapping works on a defined terminal emulator but not on another
- Your mapping works on a defined OS but not another one.

It is probably caused by one of the two following things:

- **Something intercepts the key before Vim**: It can be different applications: your OS, your desktop environment, your terminal emulator, Tmux (if you use it)…

  To troubleshoot that, you should:

  - Try to temporarily remove your `.tmux.conf` if you use tmux
  - Refer to the doc of your terminal or of your desktop environment.

  You could also refer to sister-sites like [super-user](https://superuser.com/),
  [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), etc…

  If this is the problem, you then have two solutions: either you spend
  (a lot of) time to change
  the behavior of the application which causes the problem, or you find
  another key combination to map which isn't intercepted by another
  application.
- **Your terminal emulator can't handle the key combination you're
  trying to map**:
  Terminal emulators are implemented differently and some of them
  are not able to handle some particular key combination. *(The reason why
  they can't is out of the scope of this question, see their doc or the
  sister-sites mentioned before for more details).*

  In this case, you don't have a lot of solutions: either you change your
  key for another one which is handled properly by your terminal or you
  change your terminal emulator.

## Check for the common pitfalls

Some problems in mappings are pretty recurrent and mostly related to the vimscript syntax. If your mapping has an unexpected behavior remember to check the following points:

- [**Do not put a comment on the same line as your mapping**](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6921/1841), instead put the comment on the line above. Example:

  **Don't do that:**

  ```
    inoremap ii <esc>    " ii to go back into normal mode
  ```

  Vim will consider the white spaces, the `"` and the comment as a part of the mapping which will result in an unexpected behavior.

  **Instead, do that:**

  ```
    " ii to go back into normal mode
    inoremap ii <esc>
  ```

  This is easier to read and won't mess your mapping.
- [**Do not pipe your commands with `|`**](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7244/1841). Example:

  **Don't do that:**

  ```
    nnoremap <Leader>x :w | !% python -m json.tools
  ```

  Vim will consider the pipe `|` as a command termination: When you source your `.vimrc` the mapping `nnoremap <Leader>x :w` will be created then the external command `!% python -m json.tools` will be executed.

  **Instead, do that:**

  ```
    nnoremap <Leader>x :w <bar> !% python -m json.tools
  ```

  See [an explanation about `<bar>`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2286/1841).
- **Know when to use `nore`: *always***.

  [LearnVimscriptTheHardWay](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) explain it pretty clearly: never use `map`, `nmap`, `vmap`, etc… Always prefer the nore version: `noremap`, `nnoremap`, `vnoremap`, etc…
  Why? `nore` stands for `non-recursive` mapping it means that the right-hand side of the mapping will be considered as the built-in feature even if you remmaped it. Example:

  Let's say you want to map `>` to delete a line and `-` to increment the indent of a line. If you don't use non-recursive mappings you'll do that:

  (**Do not do that it's for the example**)

  ```
    nmap > dd
    nmap - >
  ```

  When you'll hit <kbd>></kbd> your line will be deleted, that's good. But when you'll hit <kbd>-</kbd> your line will also be deleted instead of being indented. Why? Because Vim understood “I received a hit on `-` which I should translate to `>` which I should, in turn, translate to `dd`”.

  **Instead do that**

  ```
    nnoremap > dd
    nnoremap - >
  ```

  This way Vim will translate `-` as `>` and will not try to do any other translation because of the `nore`.

  **Edit note** “Always” may be an exaggerated answer in some cases you'll need to use the recursive mapping form, but it is not really common. To clarify, I'll quote @romainl from [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10130/1841):

  > Use a recursive mapping only if you intend to use any other mapping in your mapping. Use non-recursive mappings if you don't.
- **[Remember that some key combinations are equivalent](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3119/1841)**:
  Because of the hexadecimal codes that are produced some key combinations
  will be interpreted by Vim as another key. For example

  - [`<C-h>` is equivalent to `<backspace>`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3119/1841)
  - [`<C-j>` as `<enter>`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5233/1841)
  - On French keyboards `<M-a>` is the same as `á` and the same goes with all the
    `<m-` mappings. As @LucHermitte pointed out in the comment that is a
    problem with plugins using this type of mappings like vim-latex.
  - [`<C-S-a>` is equivalent to
    `<C-a>`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4290/1841). Mapping Ctrl+upper case
    letter separately from Ctrl+lower case letter is not possible cause of the
    way the terminals send ASCII codes.

  When your mapping seems to affect another key try to use another lhs
  combination, if that solves the problem inspect which hexadecimal codes
  are sent to Vim.
- **[Check that your leader is correctly defined](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8515/1841)**: If your mappings involving `<leader>` doesn't work, and you changed your leader with the command `mapleader`, check that the definition of your leader is done *before* the definition of the mappings. Otherwise, Vim will try to create mappings with a key which is not the one you think. Also, if you want to use the space bar as your leader *(which is pretty current)* make sure that you used the correct notation: `let mapleader = "\<Space>"`

## Your mapping still doesn't work?

If you went through all the steps of this answer and your mapping still doesn't work like you want, you'll probably want to ask for help on this site.

To help people to help you remember to provide some crucial information like:

- The command you used to define your mapping.
- What you are expecting your mapping to do.
- A precise description of the problem:

  “It doesn't work” won't be really helpful to people who will try to help you. You should precise if the mapping doesn't do anything or how it behaves differently than what you were expecting.
- Also indicate that you actually followed the steps described here and the results you get with `:map` and `:verbose map`

All of this will save you and the users of the site a lot of time.

---

## A useful command: `:unmap`

Sometimes it can be useful to reset a mapping without quitting Vim to help debugging its behavior.

To do so you can use the command `:unmap <key>` which will remove the mapping
assigned to `<key>` for Normal, Visual and Operating-pending modes. `:iunmap` will remove mappings for Insert mode. For other modes see `:help :unmap`.

---

## References

An excellent introduction to mapping: [learnvimscriptthehardway](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/03.html) (And a lot of other aspects of Vim)

The doc: [`:h mapping`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#mapping),
[`:h :map`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap)

[Section 20 of Vim's FAQ](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20) is about mapping and contains interesting questions ("Why does mapping the <C-...> key not work?", "I am not able to create a mapping for the  key. What is wrong?", ...)

And a bonus: [A question about best practices to find which keys to use in your mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6916/1841)

Comment: Why do ask a question which you have known the answer?

Comment: To share my experience with other users [as our moderator suggested to do](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/a/1282/1841). And because `I see a lot of questions on here where a user has a mapping which doesn't work and most of the time the reasons are pretty similar` as I said in the first line of my question, so gathering these reasons should allow to reduce the number of duplicate questions about mapping.

Comment: Well you're very welcome :-) That's the whole point of this site: sharing knowledge with fellow vimmers

Comment: A recurring problem with vim-latex and French keyboards: `<m-i>` and `é` are the same for vim, and it's the same with all meta+key: they are associated to a different diacritic.

Comment: It's also important to know how to read buffer-local mappings when we ask for their definition with `:map {sequence}` -> there is a `*` in reverse highlight in what vim prints before the associated action.

Comment: @LucHermitte Using a french keyboard everyday I had never noticed that, thanks for pointing it out! Is there a solution to mitigate this problem? (I realized that I didn't mention  the `<c-s-X>` equivalent to `<c-X>` mapping I'll add that too) EDIT: Your second point is pretty important too, I'll update, thanks!

Comment: Sometimes we really want to debug what happens. Typically when the mapping calls a plug mapping, or a function with a name impossible to remember or with complex parameters. In that case we can execute: `:debug normal {keysequence}` (without any bang), or `:debug i{keysequence}` for insert mode mappings, etc. If the key sequence contains things like special keys (`<cr>`, `<left>`, `<c-x>`, `<m-i>`, `<leader>`...). Then we need to play with  execute + double-quotes + backslash -> `:debug execute "normal \<leader>\<cr>Z"`.

Comment: Regarding meta-sequences, this is a old point of FAQ as vim-latex did chose to use things like `<m-i>`. Most users don't use the meta key as they are strongly oriented toward running Vim in the terminal -- where the meta-key cannot be used simply. We need to use gvim or macvim to notice the issue.

Comment: I see you've used "remappable" to describe a few things. This word has a strong meaning in Vim jargon, but someone who haven't read the documentation regarding `nore` may not know what we mean by that. IMO the choice of this word is unfortunate because the first _naive_ interpretation will be "cannot be remapped to another sequence of actions" or "cannot be bound to another keys sequences". Alas, "remappable" means something totally different. A link/word to explain how to interpret this word would be welcomed by newcomers I think.

Comment: @LucHermitte: You're right, I added a sentence referring to the explanation of `nore` later in the answer. I hope that clarify.

Comment: This is usefull too. :filter cmd map    it will show only map using cmd. example :filter NERDTree map

Comment: how to check the current mappings on a certain key instead of showing all mappings?

Comment: @theonlygusti I'm fairly sure we have several questions about that on the site you should look them up. Basically you will need `:verbose map <your_key>` or just `:map <your_key>`