# Window Swtiching Mappings Not Working

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

To make things a bit quicker, I've remapped the window switching commands like this:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <silent> <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <silent> <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> <C-w>l
```

My goal is to type `<C-j>`, `<C-k>`, etc., to switch between window splits. The `<C-j>` and `<C-k` bindings work, but for some reason `<C-h>` and `<C-l>` don't do anything. `<C-w>h` and `<C-w>l` work as expected.

If I run `:nmap`, I see the following for those commands:

```
...
n  <C-H>       * <C-W>h
n  <NL>        * <C-W>j
n  <C-K>       * <C-W>k
n  <C-L>       * <C-W>l
...
```

I'm using Neovim 0.1.4

**Edit**

I mispoke earlier. It looks like `<C-l>` is working as well. That just leaves `<C-h>` not working.

Comment: It's most likely because those shortcuts are being intercepted by your terminal, rather than a problem with vim. What terminal are you using?

Comment: Ah, that's totally possible. I'm using iTerm2 2.9.20160206 along with tmux 2.1. I'm not sure how to fix that though.

Comment: Have a look at http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-do-i-debug-my-mapping

Answer (score 2):

After digging into this some more, it looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2048) with Neovim and tmux. iTerm2 is interpreting `<C-h>` as a backspace and sending that instead. As a workaround, I've mapped backspace to to the action I want:

```
if has('nvim')
  nnoremap <bs> <C-w>h
endif
```