# How to see the active mapping of hjkl

Tags: key-bindings

I basically have the same problem as described [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8075/21292). In my vimrc I have

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> k gk
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> j gj
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> 0 g0
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> $ g$
```

This setting however gets somehow overwritten and I have to use `:source $MYVIMRC` to get it to work again. The answers of the question above suggest that a plugin might overwrite my setting and to check that using `:verbose :map`, which brings me to my question.

I can't find the mapping for any of my navigation keys. I see mappings for more complex key combinations like `[[` by plugins, my own mappings for navigating windows or things that seem like variables to me like `<Plug>Tex_LeftRight` (my guess that this are variables comes from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/78izt4/please_help_understand_how_to_use_plug_mapping/doufox8)). However I cannot find any mappings for the *hjkl* keys or other keys I am mapping.

Are those mapped by those `<Plug>` mappings? If so, how can I resolve these? If not, how can I find out their mappings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined the mappings as buffer-local. So the mappings are only available in the buffer active at the time of executing the mapping commands.

In your `vimrc` use:

```
nnoremap k gk
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap 0 g0
nnoremap $ g$
```

I also removed `<silence>`. The `<silence>` is only needed if you want to suppress some output, but I don't see the need here.

To check that a mapping is active, just execute `:map` to see all mappings, but that produces lots of output (as you already know).
So executing `:map k` will just show the mapping for `k`. The output would be:

```
n  k           * gk
```

- `n` means, it is a normal mode mapping.
- `k` is the char mapped
- `*` means that it is defined `noremap`
- `gk` is the value `k` is mapped to

See `:help map-listing` for details.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my main problem. But how would I be able to see these mappings?

Comment: @JeromeReinländer Updated.

Comment: ... and accepted. Thanks again for going the extra mile to not only answer my question but also helping with the underlying issue. I can verify that both parts of you answer work.