# Make gvim show Q letter (character)

Tags: vimrc, gvim, letter-case

My vim  doesn't represent the uppercase letter q `Q`?

How to fix this?

---

Here is my vimrc :

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required
syntax on
set incsearch
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4

set expandtab

autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview 

set smarttab
set expandtab
se smartindent
if exists(":nohls")
  nnoremap <silent> <C-L> :nohls<CR><C-L>
endif
set noswapfile
set pastetoggle=<F10>
set guifont=Monospace\ 6
se relativenumber
se number
nnoremap <leader>s :syntax on<CR>
nnoremap <leader>S :syntax off<CR>
colorscheme evening
set hlsearch

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_loc_list_height = 5
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 0
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

let g:syntastic_html_tidy_exec = 'tidy5'
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['standard']
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']
let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_exec = 'eslint_d'

let g:syntastic_error_symbol = '❌'
let g:syntastic_style_error_symbol = '⁉️'
let g:syntastic_warning_symbol = '⚠️'
let g:syntastic_style_warning_symbol = ''

highlight link SyntasticErrorSign SignColumn
highlight link SyntasticWarningSign SignColumn
highlight link SyntasticStyleErrorSign SignColumn
highlight link SyntasticStyleWarningSign SignColumn

nmap * <Plug>AgActionWord
vmap * <Plug>AgActionVisual
let g:vim_action_ag_escape_chars = '#%.^$*+?()[{\\|'
nnoremap <F5> :GundoToggle<CR>
nnoremap gr :grep <cword> *<CR>
nnoremap Gr :grep <cword> %:p:h/*<CR>
nnoremap gR :grep '\b<cword>\b' *<CR>
nnoremap GR :grep '\b<cword>\b' %:p:h/*<CR>
nnoremap <F12>f :exe ':silent !firefox %'<CR>
nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>
nnoremap <F12>c :exe ':silent !google-chrome %'<CR>
nnoremap <leader>% :MtaJumpToOtherTag<cr>
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
nnoremap <F12>o :exe ':silent !opera %'<CR>
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
let g:vcool_ins_rgba_map = '<A-z>'
    set so=5
call vundle#begin()
syntax enable
filetype plugin indent on

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
map <A-U> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

Bundle "justinj/vim-react-snippets"

Bundle "MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils"
Bundle "tomtom/tlib_vim"
Bundle "garbas/vim-snipmate"

Bundle "honza/vim-snippets"
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'

Plugin 'rking/ag.vim'
Plugin 'Chun-Yang/vim-action-ag'
Plugin 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
Bundle "chrisbra/histwin.vim"
Plugin 'KabbAmine/vCoolor.vim'
Bundle "sjl/gundo.vim"
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'jeffkreeftmeijer/vim-numbertoggle'
Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/xtemplate'
Bundle 'ap/vim-templates'
Plugin 'Valloric/MatchTagAlways'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'ap/vim-css-color'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-unimpaired'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-surround'

Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: This seems quite odd. I agree with @nobe4, I screenshot might be helpful. Other than that, does it behave the same if you start it on command line with `gvim -u NONE`?

Comment: @Tumbler41 , when i start with gvim -u NONE - it is all okey... There is no need for screenshot- just i press q- it prints q ? then i press shift + q ( uppercase) vim prints white spaces.... Seems this is due some plugin, right?

Comment: What's the output when you run `:imap` ?

Comment: It's either a plugin or your vimrc. The only thing that comes to mind that might be messing with that is perhaps a `conceal` highlighting command? So you might check for any of those, but that's just a stab in the dark.

Comment: @Tumbler41 added vimrc . @ DJ McMayhem , if u can , please tell , how can i redirect output of imap to buffer?

Comment: I would disable the plugins a couple at time until you find the culprit. Just tell us if there's line involving `Q` coming from `:imap`, and what it is.

Comment: @WhatsMyname [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output) might be of interest to you. Although that's really not necessary. Just look through the output on your own and see if something is mapped to `Q`. Additionally, try `:iunmap Q`

Comment: Have a look at: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/1821 and http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7723/1821

Comment: @WhatsMyname: "There is no need for a screeenshot": Yes there is, you don't give details in your question so it's a good idea to let other people know what's wrong. And since `gvim -u NONE` solves the problem the other comments are right, see nobe4's link about how to debug your `.vimrc`.

Comment: @WhatsMyname try this: `redir @a | imap | redir END | normal! "ap` and you will have the result of `imap` in your buffer, then you can post it and. But otherwise, you really should disable all your plugins/configuration and proceed granularly to detect the point of failing (I wont repeat what's already in this answer: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file/2004#2004 )

Answer (score 4):

Something in your `.vimrc` or plugins is mapped to `Q`. Run

```
:iunmap Q
```

After sourcing your `.vimrc`, and that should fix it for you.

If that works, you can make this permanent by adding that to the end of your `.vimrc`, but make sure that happens *after* every plugin call or mapping you do.

Comment: Make sure to put this *after* all the plugin calls in your vimrc if you go this route.

Comment: E31: no such mapping .... - gvim says

Comment: In my sens it solves OP's problem but does not address the issue of why this is happening.. Which may be more important than how to monkey patch it...