# "scroll-smooth" remapping works only in second buffer

Tags: vimrc, scrolling

I tried to use the "scroll-smooth" tip given in `:h tips` (see `:h scroll-smooth`).

The idea is to change `<C-U>` by a series of `<C-Y>`'s (and the same for `<C-D>` with `<C-E>`'s) :

```
map <C-U> <C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y><C-Y>
map <C-D> <C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E>
```

However it works **only when I split to another window** inside my running VIM, as if creating a buffer was necessary. The smooth scrolling works only in the second window, not the first one.

If I open another tab (`:tabf myfile`), the mapping fails again ; if I split this second tab using `:vs`, the mapping works... again only in the second window.

I tried to check `:map <C-U>` as advised in [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-debug-a-mapping), but it gives a satisfying result :

```
<C-D> <C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E>
```

**Edit**

Just to be clearer, when I say that it does not work, I mean that the screen is moved N lines down or up, but *not* with the expected "smoothing" effect.

@Nobe4, I tried  with `vim -Nu NONE`, issuing command `map <C-D> <C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E><C-E>`. Again, when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, the screen is moved a few lines down but without the smoothing effect.

Comment: It worked in my vim. Mine is 7.2

Comment: Same as @SibiCoder here, macvim 7.4. Can you try with `vim -Nu NONE` ?