# mapping to quit using "<Ctrl> + q" not coming into effect

Tags: key-bindings, quit

I am trying to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> to quit editing the file. I added the below line to my `.vimrc`

```
 nnoremap <C-q> :execute "q"<CR>
```

On pressing the above key combination, nothing happens, vim doesn't quit. No Error, no message.

Can you please help me figure out what is wrong with this setting?

**EDIT:** My vimrc file is https://gist.github.com/mdtareque/9d28c7b63b2b77d15679374a8dfbad20

I see no effect of pressing `<C-q>`, probably something is conflicting with existing setup/plugins. Above is my vimrc, almost all settings are being used.

Output of `verbose map <C-q>` is `Last set from ~/.vimrc`

FYI. I am on ubuntu 15.10, and

```
$ vim -version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 21 2015 12:30:04)
```

Comment: Works for me. What does `:verbose map <c-q>` tell you?

Comment: @Antony it says 'Last set from ~/.vimrc'. Also added link to my vimrc file

Comment: When I do `:verbose map <C-q>` I get `n <C-Q>     * :q<CR>` and then on the next line it says "Last set from ~\_vimrc." What does the first line say for you?

Comment: @Tumbler sorry I didn't see that properly. The first line says `n  <C-Q>       * :q<CR>`

Comment: You've an error on line 51, a linebreak instead of a literal ^M. Check it's not like that in your actual vimrc. This problem would show up in `:messages`.

Comment: That is intentionally put inside a abbreviation as I need a new line at that place. I don't get any error message and the abbreviation is working fine. `:messages` just displays filename, num of lines and character count and then says 'Press Enter to continue'

Comment: So it shows up as ^M in your vimrc? Because the file you posted definitely has an error.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand. Please can you delete that abbreviation if you are trying to check that file.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-debug-a-mapping/7723#7723) question yet? It could help to work through it.

Comment: `<C-q>` is a special mapping interpreted by the terminal meaning "continue output" (`<C-s>` is "stop output"). The solution is the same as in the duplicate target.

Comment: @carpetsmoker Thanks, changed the setting to `nnoremap <leader>q :q<CR>` and living peacefully now

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need the call to `execute`? This should work just fine:

```
nnoremap <C-q> :q<CR>
```

Of course if your file has been edited vim will give you a warning and won't quit.

Comment: No effect still, I have added my complete vimrc, please can you take a look. Seems something is conflicting.