# Leader shortcuts ignored

Tags: vimrc

In my vimrc I have

```
nnoremap <Leader>h :bp<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>l :bn<CR>
```

But I have to source my vimrc to enable them with (`:so $MYVIMRC`). If I do a `:map` after starting vim I will see all my other shortcuts map with leader but not this one.

Their also so no other shortcut map to `<Leader>h`.

How this can happen?

I have the same problem with `let @+=join([expand('%'),  line(".")], ':')`

[My full vimrc](https://github.com/benoittgt/dotfiles_osx/blob/master/.vimrc)

Comment: Your plugin might have unmapped. If your vimrc has the mapping and not overridden by plugin, it would have been shown. Which character you use for leader?

Comment: You have defined `mapleader` after these mappings. The default leader is a `\`. So do `\h` and `\l` work?

Comment: Run `:verbose map <Leader>h` to see what messed it up.

Comment: Your were right @PeterRincker leader was define after. Thanks a lot to all of you. PeterRincker can you post a quick answer so I can give you the karma?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `:h mapleader`:

> Note that the value of "mapleader" is used at the moment the mapping
>   is defined.  Changing "mapleader" after that has no effect for already
>   defined mappings.

Your `mapleader` is changed after your mappings in question. Meaning your mappings will use the the default `mapleader` of a `\`. e.g. Your mappings will be `\h` and `\l`. Simply define your `mapleader` before all your mappings to get the effect you desire.

For more help see `:h mapleader`