# Assign shortcut to a Split window resize Ctrl+w+|

Tags: key-bindings, macvim, split

I can expand a vertical split screen to occupy most of the area using `Ctrl+w+|`
Now I would like to map that shortcut to `Ctrl+m`. I tried the following but it failed.

```
nnoremap <C-m>    <C-W>|
```

However this does not seem to work I also tried

```
nnoremap <C-m>    <C-W-l>
```

However that fails also. Any suggestions?

Comment: For future reference about mapping debug you can have a look [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7723/1841) the use of `|` in a mapping is explained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`|` is the command separator, so it terminates the map. You need to escape it:

```
nnoremap <c-m> <c-w>\|
```

Or use `<bar>`:

```
nnoremap <c-m> <c-w><bar>
```

See `:help :bar` and `:help map_bar`.