# Map movement keys to jump words like in non-modal editors

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

Coming from non-modal editors, I still get confused with <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd> in Vim.

One feature I like about non-modal editors is jumping words by simply combining <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> arrow. So I thought I just create a Vim equivalent using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> instead of <kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> instead of <kbd>e</kbd>. Both in visual and normal mode. It looks like there are no other shortcuts interfering by default.

Does anyone know how to change `.vimrc` to map the keys accordingly?

Comment: It's working here, can you try with `nnoremap` and `vnoremap` and have a look at http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7723/1821 and http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/1821

Comment: yep, I tried and it is working in both normal/visual modes.. can you tell us how exactly it is going wrong? like what happens when you type them? did you `source ~/.vimrc` after making changes? you can close and open vim as well for changes to take effect

Comment: I did reload Vim. I also did `source ~/.vimrc`. When I hit `ctrl+h` or `ctrl+l` nothing happens, the cursor stays where it is. I just checked `:map` and it shows me this: `<C-H>   <C-W>h` and `<C-L>   <C-W>l` and more stuff. @spasic No, I don't need the arrow keys..

Comment: can you try `:nmap <C-h> b` from within vim and see if it works? I suspect you'll have to debug using links given by @nobe4

Comment: @spasic that works. I'll try a restart ;) brb. Edit: restart did not help..

Comment: I found it. There was something interfering in `.vimrc` with the bindings. I works now. I just put it to the end of the file :) Thanks for helping!!

Comment: alright, voting to close this question as off-topic then

Comment: Well, I think it may still be interesting for people who would like to achieve same behavior. I just edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution. This works fine:

```
nnoremap <C-h> b
nnoremap <C-l> e
vnoremap <C-h> b
vnoremap <C-l> e
```

Comment: Unless you're remapping a `<plug>` map (often found in plugins) always use `nnoremap` and `vnoremap`.  Maps (that are not `*nore*`) are recursive into other maps, and that becomes a mess very quickly.