# store regex searches in vimrc as mappings

Tags: key-bindings

In browsing markdown files, I find the following search useful

```
/\v^(\*|#)
```

However, when I try to map it I get an error

```
nmap <c-j> /\v^(\*|#)<cr>
```

E488: Trailing characters: #)

What would be the best way to make this work?

Comment: Questions with this problem have been asked a lot of time on this site. I made [this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) to address the most common pitfalls in mappings (and the use of `<bar> ` is one of them) maybe it would be useful for you a next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `<Bar>` instead of `|`:

```
nmap <c-j> /\v^(\*<Bar>#)<cr>
```

This is because the `|` is used as a command separator, for example:

```
nmap <C-j> :echo "Foo" | echo "bar"
```

Is actually seen as:

```
nmap <C-j> :echo "Foo"
echo "bar"
```

The `|` separates the `nmap` command from the `echo` command. In your case, Vim reads it as:

```
nmap <c-j> /\v^(\*
#)<cr>
```

Hence the somewhat confusing error.

Also see [`:help map_bar`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map_bar).

Comment: I want  similar mapping for  `inoremap "\begin{document}" "\begin{document}<CR>\end{document}<Esc>O"`