# How to map shortcut to double square brackets?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

When I type `[[` or `]]` in normal mode, cursor is jumping previous / next "class definition" during editing python (.py) file.

I want to map these shortcuts to `SHIFT + UP` and `SHIFT + DOWN`. And I added this to my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <S-Up> [[
nnoremap <S-Down> ]]
```

But when I press `SHIFT + UP`, cursor going beginning of the file, or if I press `SHIFT + DOWN`, cursor going end of the file.

How can I map these keys?

Comment: Just tried it in Gvim and Neovim in Windows, works fine. Tried it on my linux box in a terminal and doesn't work. I think the issue is what key is being sent when you press shift+up. What type of system are you running?

Comment: @jecxjo Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity. I'm working on default terminal and vim8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
nnoremap <S-Up> [[
nnoremap <S-Down> ]]
```

With the non-recursive mappings above in your `vimrc`, pressing `<S-Up>` will be exactly like pressing `[[` **in its original meaning**.

The original meaning of `[[` is (quoting `:help [[`):

```
[[    [count] sections backward or to the previous '{' in
      the first column.
```

which, usually, means "jump to the first column of the first line". Same logic for `]]`.

Since you are using non-recursive mappings, the original meaning of `[[` and `]]` is used, not the remapped versions from the Python filetype plugin.

You need recursive mappings:

```
nmap <S-Up> [[
nmap <S-Down> ]]
```

The rule is:

> Use a recursive mapping only if you intend to use any other mapping in your mapping. Use non-recursive mappings if you don't.

Comment: Its great answer, thanks! I understood the point.