# How to remap ctrl-backspace in normal and insert modes?

Tags: key-bindings

how do I remap backspace combinations? I can remap backspace itself in normal mode, but not in insert mode, and I cannot map combinations:

```
" this works:
nmap <BS> dd

" this doesn't work:
imap <BS> <Esc>dd
nmap <C-BS> dd
imap <C-BS> <Esc>dd
```

I'm using Vim 7.4 inside Terminator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping Ctrl with equal sign](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8856/mapping-ctrl-with-equal-sign)

Comment: I don't this is an *exact* duplicate of that question. `<C-BS>` is actually a special case of `<C-Key>` since it will usually send `^H` on a normal keypress and `^?` on `<C-BS>` (or vice versa, depending on your terminal).

Answer (score 4):

You need to first press <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> in insert mode before pressing <kbd>ctrl+backspace</kbd> to insert the terminal code of <kbd>ctrl+backspace</kbd>.

Your mapping will look like this:

```
inoremap ^_ <Esc>dd
```

See [`:h i_CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL%2dV):

```
CTRL-V      Insert next non-digit literally.  For special keys, the
            terminal code is inserted.
```

---

However you mapping for `<BS>` in insert mode should work (it works fine on my setup) maybe you should try the non recursive version of the mapping:

```
inoremap <BS> <Esc>dd
```

Answer (score 1):

This all works fine in gVim, so I'm presuming you're using terminal Vim.

It's hard to say definitively what is happening in your setup without more information, because the way <kbd>Backspace</kbd> works [depends on your terminal configuration](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html). However, note that `BS` is a control character, and the way that [control characters were implemented in traditional terminals](https://catern.com/posts/terminal_quirks.html) was by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key plus another key.

As such, it's entirely possible that your terminal is *already* sending <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd> when you press backspace: if this is the case pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key at the same time will have no effect.

Therefore, I suspect [statox's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13021/343) won't work for you: for me it just results in a mapping of an unmodified `<BS>`. (Whereas `nmap <C-BS>` results in a *correct* mapping of <kbd>Ctrl-Backspace</kbd> that cannot be accessed via key presses!)

Note that, in general, there are a limited number of reliable Ctrl-mappings you use in Vim. See the [this answer to a related question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8856/mapping-ctrl-with-equal-sign) and the FAQ entry it links to for more details.

Therefore, I'm afraid that the *real* answer to your question is, "Don't do that."

Answer (score 1):

My experience in terminal Vim is the same as noted by Rich; trying to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> were equally fruitless.  So this isn't a direct answer, because it appears no one-size-fits-all answer exists due to technical limitations.

In the end I compromised by using `<Leader>` as the modifier (usually set as <kbd>\</kbd>).  I should note that this doesn't work quite the same as a normal modifier key combo, as you must strike <kbd>\</kbd> before each press of <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.  With the caveats above in mind, I think these mappings should broadly work for you:

```
inoremap <Leader><BS> <C-o>dd
nnoremap <Leader><BS> dd
```

You may also want to look at your `timeoutlen` value, depending on how long you want the Leader to wait for your next key strike.

Comment: Note that you probably want to use `inoremap` and `nnoremap` here to avoid recursive mappings. See [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10130/1841) for more details.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get the usual ctrl-backspace Windows behaviour (deleting previous word) following this Vim tip:

https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-Backspace_to_delete_previous_word

You just have to put these lines on your `.vimrc`

```
" Map Ctrl-Backspace to delete the previous word in insert mode.
imap <C-BS> <C-W>
```

Alternatively, you can put the following lines on your `.vimrc` to make the behaviour more readline-ish:

```
inoremap <C-w> <C-\><C-o>dB
inoremap <C-BS> <C-\><C-o>db
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! A little explanation goes a long way, especially to prevent link rot.