# Remaping leader with :execute cannot run two commands at once

Tags: key-bindings

I have following command:

```
map <Leader>ntd :execute ":tabe! ". g:path ."l_todo.txt"<CR><ESC> :execute ":vsplit! ".g:path ."u_todo.txt"<CR>
```

Both `tabe!` and `vsplit!` commands works fine as separate remapings. I want to join those commands into one remaping.

How to make the above command to work?

Comment: You should try using only once `execute` call with a pipe `|` to chain the commands like `nnoremap <leader>a :execute "tabnew \| vsplit"<CR>`. I didn't test it but I think your command should be `map <Leader>ntd :execute "tabe! ". g:path ."l_todo.txt \| vsplit! ".g:path ."u_todo.txt"<CR>` _(Also use `nore` and a mode in your `map` command i.e. `nnoremap`, this is a good practice and can save you a lot of debugging`)_

Comment: I believe the esc in the middle is throwing an error and interrupting the map.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use two different `execute()` calls, you can simply call both commands in `execute()` like this:

```
nnoremap <Leader>ntd :execute "tabe! ". g:path . "l_todo.txt \| vsplit! " . g:path . "u_todo.txt"<CR>
```

Note the escaped piped character (`\|`) it is escaped so that vim understands that it is part of the command fed to `execute`.

Otherwise, when you source your vimrc, Vim would try to execute first `nnoremap <Leader>ntd :execute ":tabe! ". g:path . "l_todo.txt` followed by `vsplit! " . g:path . "u_todo.txt"<CR>` which is not what you want.

---

You could also improve the readability of your code like this:

```
let firstCommand="tabe! ". getcwd() . "/l_todo.txt"
let secondCommand="vsplit! " . getcwd() . "/u_todo.txt"
nnoremap <Leader>ntd :execute firstCommand . "\|" . secondCommand<CR>
```

Here we separate the different part of the string give to `execute()` to see the two actions executed.

We also use [`:h getcwd()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcwd%28%29) to get the current working directory so that we don't need a global variable to get the path.

---

Several other points about your code:

- You don't need the `:` in the commands you feed to `execute()`
- Always use the non recurcive version of `map` (i.e. `noremap`) unless [you know what you're doing](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10130/1841)
- Always specify a mode to `map` (see [`:h map-modes`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-modes))

Comment: With your refactoring, I believe changing g:path mid-session wont be reflected in the mapping. Id make first and second functions instead.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You're perfectly right, I guess one could also use [`:h getcwd()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcwd%28%29) instead of `g:path` depending on what the variable is meant to contain.