# Function to toggle set colorcolumn

Tags: vimscript, colorcolumn

I like the `set colorcolumn=80` option which highlights the column at 80 characters, however I find it annoying when working with multiple split windows.

I'd like to have an option to enable or disable the colored column by using  the `<leader>c` shortcut. I wrote a function, however my Vimscript knowledge is very limited. My only question is do you see anything wrong with this function or approach? or should I go with it?

```
" Show a colored column at 80 characters
function! ColorColumn()
if &colorcolumn == ""
    set colorcolumn=80
else
    set colorcolumn=
endif
endfunction

nmap <silent> <leader>c :call ColorColumn()<CR>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only big flaw I see in your code is the fact that you don't use the non recursive version of `nmap` (See [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10130/1841) for more details).

Also just for the sake to not use a function and make it a one liner I came up with this mapping which should do the same job:

```
nnoremap <leader>c :execute "set colorcolumn=" . (&colorcolumn == "" ? "80" : "")<CR>
```

We use `execute` to execute the command created on the fly and a ternary expression to return `""` or `80` depending on the current state of `colorcolumn`

**Edit**

If you really want to keep it under 80 characters you could use something like this:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>c :execute "set colorcolumn="
                  \ . (&colorcolumn == "" ? "80" : "")<CR>
```

But I think it's less readable than the one line version.

Comment: Thanks. I like your mapping better, but I added the <silent> stuff to hide the confirmation in the status.

Comment: @ZoltanKing Yup I didn't put the `<silent>` modifier because it was easier to test the mapping without it but that makes a nice addition :)

Comment: statox, sorry for bothering you again. It would be possible to break your code on two lines? I would like to keep it below 80 charachters. Thanks!

Comment: @ZoltanKing You're not bothering me: helping other Vimmers is pretty much the only goal of this site :) See my edit for the splitted version.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I reduced the word "colorcolumn" to just "cc" and now the one line fits well.