# Swapping two vim mappings

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I have added the following the mappings to my vimrc.
I want `K` to take me to the top line of the window and `H` to take me to the first non-empty character of the line.

```
nmap K H
nmap H ^
nmap J L
nmap L g_
```

This does not do what I want it to.
Since `K` performs `H` and `H` is mapped to (under the above mapping) take me to the first non-empty character of the line, `K` takes me to the first non-empty character of the line.

How to achieve what I want to do? I could not think of anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is the opposite problem of [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10127/1841). You need to use the non recursive version of the `map` commands [`:h :nore`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3anore):

```
nnoremap K H
nnoremap H ^
nnoremap J L
nnoremap L g_
```

And as a general rule always use the non recursive version unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: I see. A related question, if I wanted to combine this mappings with operators what should I do? Like if I wanted to do `dH` say.

Comment: @MahbubAlam You want to read the doc for operator pending mode [`:h omap-info`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#omap-info)

Comment: I tried the suggestions in `:h omap-info`, they didn't work. For instance I added `omap H ^` and typed `dH`, it didn't perform `d^`; and similarly for other mappings. Whats going on here?

Comment: @MahbubAlam Your comment is another question, we try not to answer questions in comments because it is more difficult for future readers to find it. If you're still struggling with your operator pending mode mappings, please ask a new question :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: No problem don't worry about that :)