# Make function run only on specific filetype

Tags: functions, filetype

So i have a specific function I'd like to edit in my .vimrc, so that it work only on specific filetype (eg: .vim).

The code for this example is taken from [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27340/30351) answer.

```
function OrgFold(lnum)
  let level = strlen(matchstr(getline(a:lnum), '\v^\s*\zs\"+\t'))
  if level > 0
    return '>'.level
  else
    return '='
  endif
endfunction
```

The above function essentially work on all files, but i want to know how to only make it work for .vim or whatever filetype i specify.

Comment: `autocmd FileType c call OrgFold()` is a fast way (this one will work with `c` files but you can place `java`, `python` or other filetype if you want.  You can look [there](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html#filetype-events) for more information.

Comment: thanks! didn't thought of using `call` with `FileType` @FabriceHategekimana

Comment: Note: this will launch the function when the `filetype` event is triggered (when filetype is set) but won't make it available for `c` files only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a `filetype plugin` (`:h ftplugin`).

First, you need to enable them with `filetype plugin on` (in your vimrc).

Then, you can add a file in `vim/after/ftplugin/FILETYPE.vim`, replacing `FILETYPE` with what's needed.

This file will then be sourced by vim for each file matching the filetype, allowing them to use whatever is in your plugin.

Drop your function there to make it available for this specific filetype only.

Comment: I see, so that's what some vim plugin are actually doing! But what if the function is in the vimrc then? any other way beside writing it in it's own plugin?

Comment: I guess you could [use a `filetype autocommand`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10664/file-type-dependent-key-mapping) as we could do for mappings, although I've never seen to define functions (and would not for mappings either). `ftplugin` is arguably the way to go.