# Self-define command to search a certain symbol

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, search

I want to define a command that jumps to the next closest Chinese period or Chinese comma and perhaps other punctuations, and another command that does the same but for the previous closest punctuation.

To simplify the situation, let us say I want to jump to the next/previous closest `x`, `y`, or `z`.
So I defined in `~/.vimrc`

```
map <silent> <C-k> ?[xyz]<CR> :noh<CR>
map <silent> <C-j> /[xyz]<CR> :noh<CR>
```

And try this in such line:

```
abcx1y2z3def abcx1y2z3def abcx1y2z3def
```

But when I place my cursor at `a`, press `ctrl-j`, the cursor jumps to `1`; again press `ctrl-j`, then to `2`; again press `ctrl-j`, then to `3`.

It always jumps to the character on the right of the next match.

And when I place my cursor at `f`, and press `ctrl-k`, the cursor jumps to `3`; again press `ctrl-k` many times, but no use. It only jumps to the character on the right of the previous match.

Despite that, when I press `/[xyz]<CR> :noh<CR>` or `?[xyz]<CR> :noh<CR>` explicitly, I get desired behavior.

Why? Have I made some syntax errors?

Comment: Note that it works well without the `:noh<CR>` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is at the center of your mapping:

```
map <silent> <C-k> ?[xyz]<CR> :noh<CR>
```

Indeed, the problem is  ! It moves one char right in normal mode. You can fix your mapping with:

```
map <silent> <C-k> ?[xyz]<CR>:noh<CR>
map <silent> <C-j> /[xyz]<CR>:noh<CR>
```

Have a look at `:h <Space>`. As well as this post: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7723

I also highly recommend using the `noremap` form, to prevent recursive mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-j> /[xyz]<CR>:noh<CR>
```

Comment: Oh, I thought spaces were insensitive....>< It was stupid of me QQ