# What does asterisk mean in vim mappings?

Tags: key-bindings

For example, easy clip has this mapping when you run `smap k`:

```
s  k     * <C-o>"_ck
```

The asterisk and `<C-o>` are highlighted.

Comment: You may want to read [this answer of mine](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7723/1841) which explains the `:map` commands and their output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [`:h map-listing`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-listing):

```
When listing mappings the characters in the first two columns are:

      CHAR      MODE    
     <Space>    Normal, Visual, Select and Operator-pending
        n       Normal
        v       Visual and Select
        s       Select
        x       Visual
        o       Operator-pending
        !       Insert and Command-line
        i       Insert
        l       ":lmap" mappings for Insert, Command-line and Lang-Arg
        c       Command-line

Just before the {rhs} a special character can appear:
        *       indicates that it is not remappable
        &       indicates that only script-local mappings are remappable
        @       indicates a buffer-local mapping
```

So they were created using `?noremap` commands.