# Alt-I doesn't work to inset \item in vim-latex

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vim-latex

Hello Vimmers and LaTeXers,

I cannot get Alt-I to work in vim-latex. It is supposed to insert \item depending on the environment that you are in. Do I need to activate it somehow? Is there a setting for it?
When, in insert mode, I press Alt-I in itemize environment, and for that matter anywhere, it write e with acute accent.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit: I checked `:map` and `Alt-I` does not appear in that list. What could be wrong?

Comment: Please take a look at [how to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7723/12003) and [edit] your question with more information.

Comment: Thank you @LEI. As I wrote in the question, Alt-I doesn't appear in :map list. What can I do?

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a known issue, see the comment in [ftplugin/latex-suite/envmacros.vim](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/v1.10.0/ftplugin/latex-suite/envmacros.vim#L962-L966):

```
" Only include the <M-i> mapping if the user want this. Note that it
" conflicts with inserting 'é'.
if !hasmapto("<Plug>Tex_InsertItemOnThisLine", "i") && g:Tex_AdvancedMath == 1
    imap <buffer> <M-i> <Plug>Tex_InsertItemOnThisLine
endif
```

From the vim-latex help [`altkey-mappings`](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/doc/latex-suite.txt#L745-L771):

> By default, the mappings involving the  key are turned off for compatibility with inserting non-ASCII characters. It can be enabled by setting
>
> ```
> let g:Tex_AdvancedMath = 1
> ```
>
> in your `$VIM/ftplugin/tex.vim`.

Curiously, I couldn't find this in the online documentation about [Alt Key Macros](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/altkey-mappings.html) which starts at:

> By default, typing `Alt-<key>` in Vim takes focus to the menu bar if a menu with the hotkey `<key>` exists. If in your case, there are conflicts due to this behavior, you will need to set
>
> ```
> set winaltkeys=no
> ```
>
> in your `$VIM/ftplugin/tex.vim` in order to use these maps.

See also [`:map-alt-keys`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-alt-keys) for more information on how Vim handles `Alt-<key>`.