# i_CTRL-K does not insert digraphs when in Mutt inside tmux

Tags: digraphs

I configured mutt to use vim as an editor to write emails (with `set editor=vim` in `.muttrc`), and I have noticed that when I am in tmux (with an empty `.tmux.conf`), the vim keybinding <kbd>CTRL-K</kbd> in insert mode, which is handy to insert digraphs, does not work.

Outside of Tmux && mutt, everything works fine: typing <kbd>CTRL-K</kbd> causes the character `?` to temporarily appear under the cursor, and the next two characters I type are correctly interpreted as a digraph.

Does anyone know where the error might be coming from?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe tmux consumes the keypress `C-k`, so Vim doesn't receive it. I'm not sure these shell commands will work for you, because I use an old version, but you could try `tmux list-keys`. This should list the keybindings installed in a tmux session. They can be divided into several tables. I suspect the one you should look for is called `root`, because these keybindings don't need a prefix. To see them, try `tmux list-keys -T root`. Look for the word `C-k`. If you find it, and you want to remove it, try to add this to your `.tmux.conf`: `unbind-key -T root C-k`, then restart tmux.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's what I was thinking initially, but then wouldn't the problem also manifest itself when launching vim from outside mutt? The only line that appears is the following: 

bind-key    -T copy-mode    C-k  send-keys -X copy-end-of-line, so I suppose it's probably not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Ah yes, I misunderstood your question, sorry. You're right, the issue must come from something else, but unfortunately I have no other idea.

Comment: No worry, thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: Another possibility: maybe a filetype plugin (default or third-party) installs a mapping in insert-mode using the key `C-k`. You can check this by executing: `:verb ino <c-k>`. If such a mapping exists, the file location from which it was sourced should be printed. This link might also help you: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7723/13370

Comment: I forgot: execute `:verb ino <c-k>` in a buffer where `C-k` doesn't insert digraphs. If a filetype plugin is involved, it would install buffer-local mappings, for example only in a file whose type is `mail`. The command will find a global mapping from any buffer, but it will only find a buffer-local one in the right type of buffer.

Comment: Thanks! I tried but unfortunately vim return "No mapping found", so the error is not coming from that either...

Comment: In the meantime, you could restore the functionality using another key sequence. For example, in a filetype plugin sourced when you load a `mail` buffer (example: `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/mail.vim`), you could write `ino <buffer> <c-g><c-g> <c-k>`. With this mapping, you would insert a digraph by pressing `C-g C-g`. Also, you could try to check whether Vim receives `C-k`, by inserting one literally. If you press `C-v C-k`, you should see the caret notation `^K` inside your buffer. If you don't see anything, it means something is consuming `C-k` before Vim.

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your comment. I tried `C-v C-k` and nothing appears. It turns out that, in fact, the key was received by tmux and not sent to vim, because of mappings I defined in my tmux.conf (which is strange, considering that I was opening with `tmux -f empty.conf` and it didn't work).

The problematic line in my .tmux.conf was this one: `is_vim='echo "#{pane_current_command}" | grep -iqE "(^|\/)g?(view|n?vim)(diff)?$"'`. Adding `|mutt` in the regular expression fixed it.
Thanks again for your time and for your help!

Comment: @Rastapopoulos Would you mind adding your findings as an answer? You are allowed to [answer your own questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin of the problem was that `tmux` was consuming the `C-k` keypress. I had blindly followed the instructions that came along with the [`vim-tmux-navigator`](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator) plugin at the time I installed it, which recommended using the following line in `.tmux.conf` to identify whether or not `vim` was running:

```
is_vim='echo "#{pane_current_command}" | grep -iqE "(^|\/)g?(view|n?vim?)(diff)?$"'
```

This way of detecting `vim` was not robust, and in my case it didn't detect that I was in `vim` when writing an email with `mutt`.

As it turns out, the command proposed in the `README` of the plugin was changed in [this commit](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator/commit/57701ac650990010ea97b1b4d64779d0b60c769b#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8) to one that makes the detection of vim more robust.