# How to make <S-A-Left> and <S-A-Right> work in vim within Mac Terminal

Tags: vimrc, macvim, tabbed-user-interface, macos

I'm using these keyboard shortcuts to navigate/manipulate tabs in MacVim

```
" tab navigation
nnoremap <silent> <S-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <S-Right> :tabnext<CR>

" tab movement
nnoremap <silent> <S-A-Left> :call MoveTabLeft()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <S-A-Right> :call MoveTabRight()<CR>
```

(I'm using custom functions that use `tabmove` to position current tab.)

When running vim from Terminal.app, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> work (i.e. I can navigate tabs right and left), but when using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> nothing happens. Does this require Terminal.app configuration to send some special characters, is this a feature of MacVim only or is there a vim setting I am not using properly?

Comment: I don't use macvim but I think [this answer I wrote](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) might help you to debug that.

Comment: Try `:set <s-left>=` type ctrl V then shift-left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> in insert mode, which [inserts terminal codes](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-V) received by vim, I found out that my Terminal was not sending proper escape codes to vim, therefore vim did not have correct key codes to interpret. Being a native app, MacVim recognized these key codes correctly.

Final solution was to set Terminal.app to produce key codes according [to this mapping](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScreenKeys):

```
<S-up>:      ^[[1;2A 
<S-down>:    ^[[1;2B 
<S-right>:   ^[[1;2C 
<S-left>:    ^[[1;2D 

<M-up>:      ^[[1;3A 
<M-down>:    ^[[1;3B 
<M-right>:   ^[[1;3C 
<M-left>:    ^[[1;3D 

<M-S-up>:    ^[[1;4A 
<M-S-down>:  ^[[1;4B 
<M-S-right>: ^[[1;4C 
<M-S-left>:  ^[[1;4D 

<C-up>:      ^[[1;5A 
<C-down>:    ^[[1;5B 
<C-right>:   ^[[1;5C 
<C-left>:    ^[[1;5D
```