# Separate C-m and Enter

Tags: key-bindings, tmux

I am using zsh, urxvt, tmux and in there vim. I am not 100% sure who causes the effect but I would like to bind something to ctrl and m but not to carriage return in vim. Does somebody how this is done?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I think you might want to read this https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841

Comment: nope, does not help me, because when I unmap carriage return, I unmap c-m and vise versa I want to find a way to separate these both (if it is possible - should be when they send two different keycodes), when I map ctrl-m and unbind carriage return i unmap ctrl-m again...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as Vim is concerned, `<C-M>` and `<CR>` [*are the same thing*](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/2bp9UdfZ63M/sajb9KM0pNYJ): they are represented in the same way internally.

If your terminal is truly sending different keycodes (mine doesn't) for when you press <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> vs <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then you might be able to map them separately by using their literal values when you set up the mappings.

Replace the following in your `vimrc`/Vimscript:

```
nnoremap <CR> [keypresses]
nnoremap <C-M> [other keypresses]
```

With the following,

```
nnoremap [actual ctrl-m keycode] [keypresses]
nnoremap [actual CR keycode] [other keypresses]
```

Where you enter the keycodes by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, respectively.