# How to create a vimrc macro using :sort?

Tags: macro

I tried creating the following macro:

1. search an empty line above my location
2. go down one line
3. <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>
4. find an empty line down
5. go up one line
6. `:sort`

This should sort the entire section I'm pointing at...

Here is my attempt:

```
let @q = '\/^$ N j <S-V> \/^$ n k :sort'
```

However, when trying to run the macro (using `@q`) I get one line down, and the following error: `E35: No previous regular expression`

Removing the '\' from the macro gave me this error:

```
E486: Pattern not found: ^$ N j <S-V>
```

And now I'm stuck...

**p.s.** If you have an idea how to make this macro robust so that if I don't have a line above or down (because I'm sorting till end / start of doc) I'll still be able to sort, that'd be cool, thx!

Comment: Dang I was going to self-answer a Q about creating a sort operator for vim :) good Q. Expect my answer soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
nnoremap <Leader>s Vip:sort<CR>
```

`ip` is an "inner paragraph" object, i.e. a piece of text between two empty lines.

Comment: And how do I call this?

Comment: @CIsForCookies By default `<Leader>` is equal to "backslash", so press "backslash" and then "s" in normal mode. Also, you can define it the way you like.

Answer (score 9):

You've already (rightly) accepted an answer that provides a much simpler method of achieving your goal, but I thought I'd address a few of the other issues raised by your question.

### The problems with your `:let` command

To debug your macro, a first step might be to try recording a working macro, and then comparing this with the macro created by your `let` command. I've run your command, and recorded a series of steps into the `"r` register, so lets take a look at the differences by running the [`:registers`](https://www.vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#:reg) command:

```
"q   \/^$ N j <S-V> \/^$ n k :sort
"r   /^$^MNjVnk:sort^M
```

1. Okay, so first off, the `"q` register begins with a backslash, and has another one midway though. You were correct in your guess that these are not required, but as you discovered, there are further problems with your code.
2. The `"q` register contains several spaces. Some of these should in fact be `<CR>` characters (displayed in the output with the notation `^M` meaning [`<Ctrl-M>`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14381/343)), and others are simply not required at all.
3. The `"q` register contains the string `<S-V>`, whereas it should simply contain an upper-case `V`.
4. The `"q` register contains both a second instance of the search command *and* an instance of the jump to next match motion, `n`. Only one of these is required.

### What went wrong

I think these all stem from a few misunderstandings about a). how macros are stored and/or b). how control characters are included in strings.

A macro contains a series of keystrokes, *and nothing else*. You don't separate operations with space characters: if a space character is included that equates to a press of the <kbd>Space</kbd> on your keyboard.

Similarly, if you want to run a command-line command, you need to include a `<CR>` character to emulate pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>.

The `<S-V>` notation is not required to insert upper-case characters into a string: `V` is already an upper-case character. Furthermore, in Vimscript, single quotes `'` denote a ["literal" string](https://www.vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#literal-string), which contains exactly the characters included (with the sole exception that two quotes stand for one quote). [Double-quotes `"`](https://www.vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#string) on the other hand, allow you to include control characters by using the `<angle-bracket>` notation *and* prepending the opening bracket with a backslash.

Thus, this sets the variable `v` to contain the the string `"<S-V>"`:

```
:let v = '<S-V>'
```

Whereas this is a long-winded way of setting the variable `v` to contain the string `"V"`:

```
:let v = "\<S-V>"
```

### How to fix it

So to create the correct `:let` command you have two options:

1. Enter the following into your `vimrc`: `let @q = ''` and then, having recorded the working macro into a register `"q`, paste the (current) contents of that register in between the single quotes by pressing e.g. <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. The downside of this is that, while it works, it's a bit icky to include literal control characters in your `vimrc`, so perhaps a better solution is to:
2. Rewrite the `:let` command to use a double quoted string:

   ```
   let @q = "/^$\<CR>NjVnk:sort\<CR>"
   ```

### How to improve it

Firstly, there is a better way of searching backwards than first searching forwards and then going back with `N`, which is to use [`?`](https://www.vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#?) instead of `/`.

Also, there is a better way of moving to the line after or before a blank line than running the command `j` or `k`, which is to use a ["search offset"](https://www.vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#search-offset). At the end of your search command, add `+1` to place the cursor on the line after the match, or `-1` to place the cursor on the line before the match. Because we are searching backwards, we need to first end the regular expression with `?`. (When searching forwards, you'd use `/`.)

You can repeat a search by omitting the regular expression entirely, but you can still change the search offsets or other flags.

Thus:

```
let @q = "?^$?+1\<CR>V//-1\<CR>:sort\<CR>"
```

Finally, you specifically asked about how to handle the start and end of file. You can do so by updating your regular expression.

When searching upwards, instead of searching for a blank lines we'll search for either:

- The start of the file, or,
- The first character on the line following a blank line.

We can no longer use an line-offset, but instead we need to leave the cursor on the end of the match by ending our search with the `e` offset to leave the cursor on the final character of the match.

And when searching downwards, we'll search for either:

- The end of the file, or,
- The last character on the line preceding a blank line.

To search for the start of the file you can use [`\%^`](https://www.vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#start-of-file), and to search for the end of the file you can use [`\%$`](https://www.vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#end-of-file).

To search for `A` or `B` you can use the notation [`A\|B`](https://www.vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#/bar)
 in your regular expression.

So:

```
let @q = "?\\%^\\|^$\\n.?e\<CR>V/\\%$\\|.\\n^$/\<CR>:sort\<CR>"
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer, but the quick-fix by @Matt is what I actually would have asked for, had I known... Anyway, thx for the explanation, it's very helpful!

Comment: @CIsForCookies Yep, as far as I'm concerned, Matt's answer is the *correct* one for your issue, but I thought explaining some of the surrounding context of the problems you were having would be beneficial for future readers and just for general informational purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Just to show another way to do it, I've been using [this sort operator](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/commit/7b2d610b7272f2bc9bef70f9460d09fdbadf9042#diff-348f558bb82e829368a033e1748b8bd6) for about 2.5 weeks and loving it.

Once you set up the code, you can use `gs` (or another mapping of your choice) as follows:

- in normal mode as an operator like `d`, `y`, `gu`, or others to sort a range of lines
- in visual mode, to sort the highlighted lines

Note that, because we are sorting, the operator always forces the motions to be linewise.

So you could then do `gsip`, similarly to the accepted answer.

You'll need the following code:

```
" ~/.vim/autoload/sort.vim
function! sort#operator(type, ...) abort

  let l:visual = a:0

  if l:visual
    '<,'>sort
  else
    '[,']sort
  endif

endfunction
```

and

```
" ~/.vim/plugin/sort_op.vim

if exists('g:loaded_sort_op')
  finish
endif
let g:loaded_sort_op = 1

nnoremap <silent> gs :set operatorfunc=sort#operator<CR>g@
vnoremap <silent> gs :<C-u>call sort#operator(visualmode(), 1)<CR>
```

(It doesn't make sense to add the single line variant `gss` since we are sorting.)

Comment: Good stuff, although simple `vnoremap <silent>gs :sort<CR>` should be sufficient for the visual mode in this case.

Comment: @Matt lol you're probably right—I had been using this "pattern" for another operator I built that same day, and didn't consider it. The advantage of my way is that the implementation can change without changing the interface. (For example, if I needed to prompt for `:sort` options or some such)