# Why does this binding break the quickfix window?

Tags: vimrc, quickfix

If I have this vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
nnoremap <C-m> ^^
```

When I try to open a file from the quickfix window by pressing enter nothing happens.

If I comment out the last line, so the vimrc is this:

```
set nocompatible
" nnoremap <C-m> ^^
```

Then the quickfix window works as expected.

Note that those two lines are the *entire* vimrc file. No plugins are being loaded either.

I've had the above mapping in my vimrc for over a decade and have always had strange issues with the quickfix window. I finally figured out what's causing it but I'm still stumped, what's going on here?

Comment: Not directly but it did lead me to the solution. I'll add an answer to this question.

Comment: Related question: [Separate C-m and Enter](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14379)

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out, and decided to just remove the mapping.

It's happening because (at least in my environment, using vim in a terminal over SSH) there's no distinction between `<C-m>` and `<CR>`, they're one and the same to vim. If I remap `<C-m>` in normal mode, I'm also remapping `<CR>` in normal mode. I don't tend to press enter in normal mode so I didn't notice, except in the quickfix window.

I could modify the mapping to not apply in the quickfix window as suggested in the comments, but in this case I just removed the mapping, as it seems like an all around bad idea.

Comment: `<C-m>` is always the same as `<CR>` in terminals. I wrote a more in-depth explainer some time ago at https://bestasciitable.com