# How to run internal Vim terminal at current file's dir?

Tags: terminal, working-directory

When I edit file:

`/home/me/projects/myproj/src/util.c`

I would like to start terminal at:

`/home/me/projects/myproj/src`.

With Vim version > 8 I can run `:terminal` but it always starts at folder in which I've opened Vim (which is `/home/me/projects/myproj`)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am grateful to @statox for useful hints, but as I don't wont to change current dir each time I come to following:

```
map <F6> :let $VIM_DIR=expand('%:p:h')<CR>:terminal<CR>cd $VIM_DIR<CR>
```

Comment: I don't quite get why this doesn't work for me; typing `:echo $VIM_DIR` outputs the correct directory, but the command fails :(

Comment: @Krish [How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) might help.

Comment: @Krish try `:terminal<CR>Acd $VIM_DIR<CR>`

in Neovim atleast, terminal opens up in normal mode, so you get into insert mode first (a/i/A/I) to type in the rest of the command

Comment: Is there a way to do this as a command instead of as a mapping?

Comment: @Thayne here is what i have in my vimrc for neovim. (replace terminal with shell for vim, also don't need the A<CR> i don't think):
`command Cdot normal! :lcd%:h<CR>:terminal<CR>A<CR>`

Comment: If you don't want to instantly lose 3 lines whenever you open a terminal with this method tack on a clear<CR> to the end of this mapping.

Answer (score 10):

See [`:h :cd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3acd) and [`:h :lcd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3alcd).

`:cd` changes the current directory for all the windows while `:lcd` changes the current directory for the current window.

You can change the current directory to the directory containing the current file with:

```
:cd %:p:h
```

And you can use `set autochdir` in your `.vimrc` to change the current working directory whenever you open a file, switch buffers, delete a buffer or open/close a window.  It will change to the directory containing the file which was opened or selected. (see [`:h 'autochdir'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27autochdir%27))

Also note that the doc mentions that `autochdir` may break some plugin and [this wikia page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file) suggests the following autocommand to replace this setting:

```
autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h
```

Comment: Note that when a local directory is in use for the current window, it's best to avoid `:cd`. When `exists('*haslocaldir') && haslocaldir()` is true, always use `:lcd`. Otherwise, we have the choice.

Comment: Put it all together: `split | lcd %:h | terminal ++curwin`. May want to wrap this up into a command. e.g. `command! -nargs=* Terminal split | lcd %:h | terminal ++curwin <args>`

Comment: @PeterRincker With the ++curwin option to `terminal, it seems to be passing the "++curwin" as an argument to my shell rathe rthan opening the terminal in the current window

Comment: According to [`:h :term`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#%3Aterminal): `++curwin` is a valid option. Is it possible you are using an older version of Vim or maybe Neovim?

Answer (score 3):

Building on the other answers, in neovim, you can do:

```
command! LocalTerm let s:term_dir=expand('%:p:h') | below new | call termopen([&shell], {'cwd': s:term_dir })
```

(this assumes that your shell is a single command with no options)

Comment: this is neovim only

Comment: very helpful. I`m using project.nvim and just this answer worked for me.

Comment: I add `|:startinsert` to last for going to insert mode, how can I use `<UP>` arrow for getting the last termianl command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Vim keymap with a single function. In my case, the leader is a space.

Short cut to open terminal <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

What the Lua function does:

1. It switches to directory of current file.
2. Opens terminal on current file's directory.
3. Switches to "insert" mode by itself.

The Lua function is as following:

```
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>t", function()
   vim.cmd("cd %:p:h")
   vim.cmd("terminal")
   vim.cmd("startinsert")
end)
```

Comment: This changes Vim's pwd, which as a side-effect is not present in other answers and might be worth highlighting as a tradeoff.