# Mapping using tpope/vim-surround only works with command

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-vim-surround, user-commands

I have this mapping to surround a Word with jQuery id selector `$("#...")` and it works fine using a command:

```
command! JqId normal viwo^[i#^[ysiW"ysiW)i$^[E
nnoremap <Leader>jqid :JqId<CR>
```

But I cannot make it works only with the mapping, it inserts the `$` sign, but the vim-surround commands do nothing:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>jqid viwo^[i#^[ysiW"ysiW)i$^[E
```

I also tried this (for testing purposes) and it doesn't work either:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>jqid ysiW"
```

Any hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT*:

Your mapping doesn't work because you are in a rare case where you want to use `nmap` instead of `nnoremap`: You want to use in a mapping an already defined mapping. Using `nnoremap` you said to Vim "use the default behavior of `ysiW"`" instead of "use the behavior defined by a plugin"

---

If I understand your mapping correctly you want to be able to transform

```
foo
```

into

```
$("#foo")
```

Vim surround is useful when you need to provide a different character to surround your word, here you know that you will always use it with the same characters so you could just use built-in motions. For example something like this:

```
nnoremap <yourkey> bi$("#<Esc>ea")
```

This mapping will work if you are not on the first character of the word it would need a bit of work to be more robust but what I want to say with this answer is don't use a plugin if you don't actually need it.

Comment: Thank statox, you undertand perfectly. I think the "first character issue" can be fixed with viwo<Esc> ([idea from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1xzfjy/go_to_start_of_current_word_if_not_already_there/)).

But I would also like to know the problem of executing the original mapping without the command (with the command it works). So I think I'm not understanding something about the basics of executing stuff through mappings.

Comment: @raul.vila See my edit :)

Comment: Thanks! It was that. I thought the recursivity worked in reverse (to allow other mappings to invoke the one which is being defined). Now I know :D.

Comment: @raul.vila For the next time you have an issue with a mapping you might be interested in [this generic answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) I made some times ago.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can setup a customized "surrounding".

```
let g:surround_{char2nr('i')} = "$(\"#\r\")"
```

Now you can use the "i" surrounding with all your surrounding operators, `ys`, insert mode `<c-s>` / `<c-g>s`, visual mode (`S`), etc.

For more help see:

```
:h surround-customizing
:h curly-braces-names
:h :let
:h char2nr()
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, it make sense if I'm using vim-surround. But the "nore" option was what I was really missing.