# How to disable Help menu in insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to map `<M-h>` to <kbd>←</kbd> in insert mode. I add `imap <M-h> <Left>` to .vimrc.
But if I press `<M-h>`, Help menu will pop up.
How to disable this and force `<M-h>` to <kbd>←</kbd> in insert mode?

[image]

Comment: [How to debug a mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841)  Which helpmenu pops up? Your terminal's one? Then the problem doesn't come from Vim.

Comment: If this help menu comes from the terminal, that means, that the actual key mapping does not reach vim but is intercepted by the terminal or your system. So please be more specific, what kind of help menu?

Comment: @statox, Christian Brabandt, I'm using gvim. Just upload the screenshot.

Comment: @statox, [`'winaltkeys'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27winaltkeys%27) case isn't covered by "How to debug a mapping?"

Answer (score 1):

This is probaby what you want: `:imenu disable Help`

Comment: Tried the command, but when press alt+h, the Help menu is still popping out.

Comment: are you sure you were in insert mode?

Comment: Yes, I was in insert mode, just tried again.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way: remove the menu bar `:set guioptions -=m`.

Thanks below link.
[How to hide the menu/tool bar of gvim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525518/how-to-hide-the-menu-tool-bar-of-gvim)

Answer (score 1):

The default gvim menus are located at $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim. You can copy this file into your local vim settings, disable loading of the default menus with `:let did_install_default_menus=1` in your .vimrc (see `:help menu.vim`), and then source the copy which you will edit. You'll notice that the commands to add the Help menus (like `:an 9999.10 &Help.&Overview<Tab><F1> :help<CR>`) have ampersands before the 'H' in 'Help'; this ampersand decides shortcut keys. You could then change the shortcut key, or remove it altogether while still retaining the Help menu.

Answer (score 1):

`Alt` key is in competition between mappings and menus.

To choose which one has the priority, you'll need to set [`'winaltkeys'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27winaltkeys%27). Set it to `no` in order to completely ignore menu alt-shortcuts.

This solution is less intrusive than the one where menu bar is completely removed. The menu is still displayed, we just loose the shortcuts.