# <Esc> key mapping seems to be not working in my vim 8.0 on my Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vimrc, linux-ubuntu

I have `inoremap jj <ESC>` in my `vimrc` on my `Ubuntu 16.04`. I have no idea why my `jj` not working and its just typing literally `<ESC>` in my text file for my `jj` press.

Any idea how can I get around this?
My full `vimrc`:

```
map j gj
map k gk

set smartindent
set nowritebackup  
set noswapfile     
set nobackup

colo delek
inoremap jj <ESC>
```

Comment: Id bet money its the first mapping causing problems. What happens if you use `nnoremap` instead of `map`?

Comment: If you can't make the mapping with `<esc>` to work you can try `inoremap jj ^[ ` where `^[` is inserted by pressing `<ctrl-v><Esc>` (Also I wrote a question which may help you [How to debug a mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) )

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble: It looks like nnoremap not working either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of your vimrc (before your mappings), you should add:

```
set nocompatible
```

It will change many behaviours inside vim  (see help), and will certainly solve your problem.

Here is a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/328167/map-function-keys-like-cr-in-vim-on-cygwin) on SuperUser.

Edit:

If this solution works, however it means that the `compatible` option has not been automatically unset by 
Vim, which however should happen in most cases (see `:h compatible-default`).

It probably means that you're not using a *user* vimrc configuration file, like `~/.vimrc`. In this 
case, Vim would unset the `compatible` option automatically. So a better solution would be to put
your configuration in such a file (see `:h .vimrc` for other possible names that Vim will be able
to detect).

Comment: That will not change anything see [`:h 'nocompatible'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27nocompatible%27): `When a |vimrc| or |gvimrc| file is found while Vim is starting up, this option ['nocompatible'] is switched off`. This command shouldn't be in your vimrc actually because it reset different settings which can cause trouble when you source your vimrc after start up

Comment: @statox: From `:h compatible-default`: `[...] then the option will be set to 'nocompatible'. [...] Note that this does NOT happen when a system-wide vimrc file was found.` Maybe it's the case for the OP? And how could the described behaviour be explained otherwise than with `compatible` set?

Comment: @yolenoyer Might be worth adding that info to your answer, and maybe also the suggestion to move the configuration into a personal `.vimrc` as an alternative solution?

Comment: @yolenoyer: my issue has been resolved. it was `/etc/vim/vimrc`

Comment: thank you so much. I changed computers, and my vim settings just stopped worked as usual. Only after `set nocompatible`, my commands from vimrc started working again. I have installed and uninstalled and removed all vim folders, but the problem persisted, I don't know why.