# How can I detect which command triggers a shortcut in a third-party package?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-ale

I remap Shift + k to `noh`, but once I installed [ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale), it is no longer working since one of the command on the package uses the shortcut.

At least as far as I know, I feel that it is related to docstring on Python (likely it outputs the content of the docstring in a file), but even though I searched on the documentation (`help ale`) using seemingly relevant keywords, I failed to detect which command triggers the shortcut. Reading the documentation all from the top to the bottom is not a solution here (I wish you understand it...).

So is there any way to find which function triggers the shortcut on a third-party library? What I want is prioritize my own custom key remapping over the third-party's.

Comment: type `:verbose nmap K` and `:verbose nmap <buffer> K` and see what it says

Comment: This sounds like a plugin is trying to "extend" the default behavior of `K`, which I’ve encountered before. Didn’t see any issues with ALE doing so; does this *only* happen in Python buffers?

Comment: You might want to have a read at [How do I debug a mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841)

Comment: @Mass K Thanks. The result is `*@:call pymode#doc#find()<CR>
        Last set from ~/.nvim/dein/.cache/init.vim/.dein/ftplugin/python/pymode.vim` which appears before my own custom setting. Is there any way to prioritize my own shortcut? (Or should I open a new question?)

Comment: since this is specific to the plugin pymode, you should read the plugin's documentation.  In this case it appears `let g:pymode_doc=0` or `let g:pymode_doc_bind='gK'` would work