# Swap `j` and `gj`

Tags: key-bindings

I use vim a lot to edit tex files. 
When I have lines spanning multiple display lines, most of the time I want to navigate through them with `gj` not `j` (i.e. according to displayed lines, not physical lines).

I tried putting the following lines in my `.vimrc` but, not surprisingly, got an error message `recursive mapping`:

```
nmap j gj
nmap gj j
```

How do I properly swap the effects of two commands?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. My first thought was to do it this way:

```
nnoremap j :normal! gj<CR>
nnoremap gj :normal! j<CR>
```

Call the original `gj` or `j` using normal mode; the exclamation mark prevents them from being associated with any current mappings.

See `:help normal` for more details.

A simpler method was provided in the comments by [@statox](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox):

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap gj j
```

A non-recursive mapping is also prevented from being recognised during subsequent mappings.

Comment: Wouldn't `nnoremap j gj` and `nnoremap gj j` be enough?

Comment: @statox that's also what I just realized (see comment under other answer)

Comment: @Bananach Just so you know: in the future, you'll probably always want to use the nonrecursive version of the map commands. I wrote a little about that [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) (in the "common pitfalls" section) along with some useful stuff to know when you play with mappings :)

Comment: For an in-depth exploration of replacing movement keys with their `g` counterparts, two good resources are http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_cursor_by_display_lines_when_wrapping and
https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2k4cbr/problem_with_gj_and_gk/

Comment: Thanks @statox that checks out and I have added it to the answer