# Cannot set (let) mapleader and use <leader> in global vimrc

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, linux-arch, linux-debian

I'm using basic version vimrc from https://github.com/amix/vimrc. No problem if I put my vimrc at `/home/{user}/.vimrc`, but if I put it in `/etc/vimrc` (arch) or `/etc/vim/vimrc` (debian), it becomes a problem.

The problem is: I cannot use:

```
let mapleader = ","
```

And then make a mapping that uses `<leader>`:

```
map <leader>tf :tabnew **/*    "fuzzy search file and open in new tab
map <leader>tn :tabnew<cr>     "open a blank new tab
```

Or just mapping a `<space>`:

```
map <space> /
map <c-space> ?
```

At my arch workstation, I open vim from konsole. In my debian server, I ssh-ed to open it (so, a tty).

**Edit (more information) with command `:map` with global vimrc (from @statox link):**

```
   0             ^
   <Leader>m   * mmHmt:%s/<C-V><cr>//ge<cr>'tzt'm
v  <C-S-k>       :m'<-2<cr>`>my`<mzgv`yo`z
v  <C-S-j>       :m'>+<cr>`<my`>mzgv`yo`z
n  <C-S-k>       mz:m-2<cr>`z
n  <C-S-j>       mz:m+<cr>`z
   <leader>cd    :cd %:p:h<cr>:pwd<cr>
   <leader>te    :tabedit <c-r>=expand("%:p:h")<cr>/
   <leader>tf    :call fzf#run({'sink': 'tabedit'})<cr>
   <leader>tc    :tabclose<cr>
   <leader>tn    :tabnew<cr>
   <leader>tz    :tabnew **/*
n  <c-space>   * ?
n  <space>     * /
```

So, most of the keys are not mapped correctly except a few like `map 0 ^`

**And this is `:map` command when I drop the vimrc to `~/.vim/vimrc`**

```
   0             ^
   ,m   * mmHmt:%s/<C-V><cr>//ge<cr>'tzt'm
v  <C-S-k>       :m'<-2<cr>`>my`<mzgv`yo`z
v  <C-S-j>       :m'>+<cr>`<my`>mzgv`yo`z
n  <C-S-k>       mz:m-2<cr>`z
n  <C-S-j>       mz:m+<cr>`z
   ,cd    :cd %:p:h<cr>:pwd<cr>
   ,te    :tabedit <c-r>=expand("%:p:h")<cr>/
   ,tf    :call fzf#run({'sink': 'tabedit'})<cr>
   ,tc    :tabclose<cr>
   ,tn    :tabnew<cr>
   ,tz    :tabnew **/*
n  <c-space>   * ?
```

Comment: What is the error message you got?

Comment: there's no error message. It just the 'shortcut' is not functioning.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but I highly recommend `noremap` variants over plain `map`

Comment: You need to specify clearly what you expect, what you type, whether the mapping is used before you apply the foreign vimrc or not. I see `<leader>tf` is not in the foreign vimrc while `map <space>` is.

Comment: Since you said that simply mapping `<space>` doesn't work you could check this question of mine [How to debug a mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) if you follow the steps of the answer and report the results here it might be easier to help you. Also the usual pitfalls: - don't put a comment on the same line as a mapping, specify the mode of your mappings (`nmap` instead of `map`) and use the nonrecursive version of the commands (`nnoremap` instead of `nmap`)

Comment: Also I don't think that putting your complete vimrc in `/etc` is a good idea: your vimrc contains your mappings and your configurations, other users don't need such a complete generic vimrc (since they can override it with their own vimrc). And if you do that so you can have your configuration when editing a file as root, don't edit files as root use `sudoedit` instead.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, tried that, no effect.

Comment: @tivn: sorry, I don't understand what you mean with foreign vimrc. But the point is, all the mapping with `<leader>` is not processed. You can try to map it to anything, but it won't work. Same with `<space>`. Nearly all mapping won't work if I place it at global config folder (`/etc/`)

Comment: @statox I've updated the info thanks to your link. And I'm not put comment on the same line as mapping. For map mode, I've tried it with nmap vmap, nnoremap, vnoremap, etc, with no success.

Comment: @statox: Mainly just me using vim, so it's not a problem to put vimrc in global configuration `etc`. Sometimes I juggle between users and use vim. If I must put vim to each users, it's annoying. When I updating my vimrc, I must override all local vimrc for each user.

`sudoedit`? Noted. Will try that.

Comment: @Tonny, by foreign I mean the vimrc that you download from Internet. AFAIK, vim does not read `~/.vim/vimrc` . Try move it to `~/.vimrc` or ensure you `source` it from this file if it is exist.

Comment: @tivn vim does in fact read `~/.vim/vimrc` (theres a specific order it searches in though)

Comment: @Ben Knoble I stand corrected. On vim 7.3 of my Macbook, it does not read `~/.vim/vimrc` but on vim 7.4 of my Linux it is indeed read unless `~/.vimrc` exist.

Comment: @tivn: `~/.vim/vimrc` is not a global, but a local config, like @D. Ben Knoble stated. And all local config, whether `~/.vimrc` or '~/.vim/vimrc' is working correctly. What's not working is when you placed the `vimrc` to `/etc` (make it global)

Comment: What version of vim? I can't understand why it wouldn't parse `<leader>` correctly (but only sometimes)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: The newest Vim (8.x.x)

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've just seen is that if `cpo` contains `<`, then special characters like `<leader>` won't be handled right:

```
                                *cpo-<*
        <   Disable the recognition of special key codes in |<>|
            form in mappings, abbreviations, and the "to" part of
            menu commands.  For example, the command
            ":map X <Tab>" results in X being mapped to:
                '<' included:   "<Tab>"  (5 characters)
                '<' excluded:   "^I"     (^I is a real <Tab>)
            Also see the 'k' flag above.
```

The default for `vi` (note: not `vim`) is all flags—perhaps the global vimrc is being read by `vi` or `vim` in compatible mode?

Comment: It’s this. The existence of a user vimrc causes `nocompatible` to be set implicitly, but the existence of a system-wide  vimrc does *not* (See `:help compatible`). Adding an explicit `set nocompatible` will fix this, and is probably a good idea generally.

Answer (score 0):

I'll list my alternative ideas that doesn't solve the actual problem:

1. put the vimrc file elsewhere (prefer in `/etc/skel/.vim/vimrc`) then make a softlink to local `.vim/vimrc`. The command: `mkdir .vim && sudo ln -s /etc/skel/.vim/vimrc .vim/vimrc`

Comment: Hey tonny, did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: @guntbert lol welp /shrug I can hope

Comment: @D.BenKnoble nope. Still not solved. Until now, I put the .vimrc in my users .vim folder.