# mapping does not work even if I have set it up in config file

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, microsoft-windows

I am using Neovim on Windows using [Cmder](http://cmder.net/) console emulator. I find that using `[NUM]<Ctrl-6>` to change to buffer `[NUM]` does not work on Windows. Following discussions [here](https://github.com/onivim/oni/issues/2002). I have set up a mapping:

```
nnoremp <C-6> <C-^>
```

But I still can not switch buffers using `Ctrl-6`. Any ideas what is wrong?

Edit: After going through the [post here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-debug-a-mapping). I find that `<C-6>` is correctly mapped to `<C-^>`. So the reason may be that some application intercept `<C-6>` before vim can receive it. But it is hard to find the real cause.

Comment: [Something I wrote](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) to help you debug that and give us more relevant information (Assuming that you made a typo in your question and don't actually use `nnoremp`)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to debug more and edit my question later.

Comment: Have you tried `<C-^>` at all?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, I have tried `<C-^>` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps <kbd>Ctrl-6</kbd> is not recognized.

Open (neo)vim and go into insert mode. Then enter <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl-6</kbd>. See what it prints. 
For me on Ubuntu (GNOME-Terminal) this prints `^^`. So here <kbd>Ctrl-6</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl-^</kbd>.

See what it prints for you, then you are able to fix your mapping.

---

In the way described above, you can check if a control-key is mappable.

To check if <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> is mappable, you go to insert mode and hit <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd>. This prints `^X` (this is one character). So  <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> is mappable.

Now we would like to map <kbd>Ctrl-#</kbd>: Again <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl-#</kbd>. This just prints `#`. So <kbd>Ctrl-#</kbd> is not mappable, as it is identical to <kbd>#</kbd>. (Tested with GNOME-Terminal.)

Some keys might already be used as shortcut by the terminal. In that case the terminal consumes the key and does not send it to Vim. If this is the case, check if you can reconfigure shortcuts.

Note that the terminal is in control here. (Neo)Vim only get those keys, that the terminal sends to it.

Also note that gVim has more capabilities. E.g. gVim is able to distinguish between <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>kHome</kbd> (NumPad). Vim in GNOME-terminal is not.

Comment: It does not print anything.

Comment: @jdhao See my update.