# Repeat complicated motions

Tags: cursor-motions, repeated-commands

I know that similar things were asked here several times. I know that to repeat a motion `;` works. Unless it doesn't(in case there is count for example), but then `repmo.vim` usually works. And I know that `.` works for changes.

The thing is that `repmo.vim` is stupid, and thus provides no solution for complicated things such as `[m`,`[c`, `[M`. When I tried to do so(add this motion to its list), it didn't work.

So, any solution for this that I missed? 
Doing `norm ']m'` and then `@:` is an option, but I don't really like it. The forward and rev capability of `repmo.vim` is nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Plugin [*repmo-vim*](https://github.com/Houl/repmo-vim) by Andy Wakula

The plugin [#2174](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2174) listed on https://www.vim.org/scripts is, according to the description, outdated:

> 2016 Nov 22 started a new script at https://github.com/Houl/vim-repmo

The new plugin on github works for me when repeating, e.g. `]m`/`[m` and `]M`/`[M` with `;` and `,`. My minimal configuration looks like using vim8 packages (vim 8.1.560 on macOS 10.12):

```
~/.vim
❯ tree
.
├── pack
│   └── repeat-complicated-motions
│       └── start
│           └── repmo-vim
│               ├── README.markdown
│               └── autoload
│                   └── repmo.vim
└── vimrc

5 directories, 3 files
```

```
" ~/.vim/vimrc
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim

map <expr> ; repmo#LastKey(';')|sunmap ;
map <expr> , repmo#LastRevKey(',')|sunmap ,

" Still repeat fFtT (now with counts):
noremap <expr> f repmo#ZapKey('f')|sunmap f
noremap <expr> F repmo#ZapKey('F')|sunmap F
noremap <expr> t repmo#ZapKey('t')|sunmap t
noremap <expr> T repmo#ZapKey('T')|sunmap T

" Now following can also be repeated with `;` and `,`:
for keys in [ ['[[', ']]'], ['[]', ']['], ['[m', ']m'], ['[M', ']M'], ['[c', ']c'] ]
    execute 'noremap <expr> '.keys[0]." repmo#SelfKey('".keys[0]."', '".keys[1]."')|sunmap ".keys[0]
    execute 'noremap <expr> '.keys[1]." repmo#SelfKey('".keys[1]."', '".keys[0]."')|sunmap ".keys[1]
endfor
```

Example java file:

```
public class Factorial
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   final int NUM_FACTS = 100;                                 // ; after [m
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_FACTS; i++)
            System.out.println( i + "! is " + factorial(i));
    }                                                              // , after ]M

    public static int factorial(int n)
    {   int result = 1;                                            // [m
        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            result *= i;                                           // CURSOR
        return result;
    }                                                              // ]M
}
// vim: ft=java
```

Also when I open a diff (e.g. with `:Gdiff` from vim-fugitive), repeating `]c` and `[c` are possible.

#### `<Plug>` mappings of ftplugins

Another possible issue with `[m`, `[M` is that you have to remap them for filetypes with overwrites and you want to use the overwrites. Examples are python, vimscript, and ruby.
Unfortunately, many ftplugins do not provide them as `<plug>` mappings [which repmo-vim needs](https://github.com/Houl/repmo-vim#foreign-scripts-support).

The ftplugin [vim-pythonsense](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-pythonsense) provides them as `<plug>` mappings:

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
map <expr><buffer> ]] repmo#Key('<plug>(PythonsenseStartOfNextPythonClass)', '<plug>(PythonsenseStartOfPythonClass)')|sunmap <buffer> ]]
map <expr><buffer> [[ repmo#Key('<plug>(PythonsenseStartOfPythonClass)', '<plug>(PythonsenseStartOfNextPythonClass)')|sunmap <buffer> [[
map <expr><buffer> ][ repmo#Key('<plug>(PythonsenseEndOfPythonClass)', '<plug>(PythonsenseEndOfPreviousPythonClass)')|sunmap <buffer> ][
map <expr><buffer> [] repmo#Key('<plug>(PythonsenseEndOfPreviousPythonClass)', '<plug>(PythonsenseEndOfPythonClass)')|sunmap <buffer> []
map <expr><buffer> ]m repmo#Key('<plug>(PythonsenseStartOfNextPythonFunction)', '<plug>(PythonsenseStartOfPythonFunction)')|sunmap <buffer> ]m
map <expr><buffer> [m repmo#Key('<plug>(PythonsenseStartOfPythonFunction)', '<plug>(PythonsenseStartOfNextPythonFunction)')|sunmap <buffer> [m
map <expr><buffer> ]M repmo#Key('<plug>(PythonsenseEndOfPythonFunction)', '<plug>(PythonsenseEndOfPreviousPythonFunction)')|sunmap <buffer> ]M
map <expr><buffer> [M repmo#Key('<plug>(PythonsenseEndOfPreviousPythonFunction)', '<plug>(PythonsenseEndOfPythonFunction)')|sunmap <buffer> [M
```

Also the ftplugin [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) provides them as `<plug>` mappings and the configuration becomes:

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim
map <expr><buffer> ]] repmo#Key('<plug>(vimtex-]])', '<plug>(vimtex-[[)')|sunmap <buffer> ]]
map <expr><buffer> [[ repmo#Key('<plug>(vimtex-[[)', '<plug>(vimtex-]])')|sunmap <buffer> [[
map <expr><buffer> ][ repmo#Key('<plug>(vimtex-][)', '<plug>(vimtex-[])')|sunmap <buffer> ][
map <expr><buffer> [] repmo#Key('<plug>(vimtex-[])', '<plug>(vimtex-][)')|sunmap <buffer> []
map <expr><buffer> ]m repmo#Key('<plug>(vimtex-]m)', '<plug>(vimtex-[m)')|sunmap <buffer> ]m
map <expr><buffer> [m repmo#Key('<plug>(vimtex-[m)', '<plug>(vimtex-]m)')|sunmap <buffer> [m
map <expr><buffer> ]M repmo#Key('<plug>(vimtex-]M)', '<plug>(vimtex-[M)')|sunmap <buffer> ]M
map <expr><buffer> [M repmo#Key('<plug>(vimtex-[M)', '<plug>(vimtex-]M)')|sunmap <buffer> [M
```

If you want to use the ones in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/{`[`python`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim)`,`[`ruby`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/ruby.vim)`,`[`vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/vim.vim)`}.vim` you have to rewrite them as `<plug>` mappings and put them into `repmo#Key`.

What file types are you interested in?

Comment: I spend like two hours trying to presuade vim to load it. It did work in one of my environment (I have gui and command line environment). But no more. I simply source it from .vimrc before anything else. Even though it is on the autoload folder it ignores it. I give up.

Comment: I can see that autoload was run from echoing one of the variables. But motions are not repeated. It did work earlier.

Comment: Hi eyal karni. Sorry to hear that you could not make it work. I have updated the question with a more explicit description of a minimal config with java code for illustration. Could you backup your  vim config and work with an empty `~/.vim` folder? Place everything I mentioned in my answer accordingly (`$ git clone https://github.com/Houl/repmo-vim ~/.vim/pack/repeat-complicated-motions/start/repmo-vim` and the vimrc should be identical). Also please post the result from `:nmap [m` which should be `nox [m * repmo#SelfKey('[m', ']m')` and your vim version 8.x.xxxx and OS.

Comment: Also check out [How to debug a mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-debug-a-mapping) and [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file).

Answer (score 1):

I have created a small [vim-remotions](https://github.com/vds2212/vim-remotions) plugin that allows to repeat the last motion using the <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> keys (like for the `f` and `t` motions).

By default it repeats the following motions: `]m`, `]M`, `]]`, `][`, `}`, `g;`, `]b`, `]l`, `]q`, `]t`, `]g`.

It use the motion as they are defined in the buffer by the `filetype`.

The list of motions it repeats is configurable.

It can repeat the motion and their count or only the motion.

It can repeat the motion in the direction of the initial motion (like <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> are doing for `f` and `t`) or in the direction of the document if considered more intuitive.

Thanks to @romainl for his hints.

Comment: Hi Vivian. It looks like you copied this answer from another one of your answes [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/43332/how-to-repeat-motions-in-general-and-in-particular-the-ones-defined-in-filetype). In general if the same answer can apply to the same question it may be a duplicate, but in this case it looks like you are recommending your plugin. Can you please edit your answer to address the question's specifics.

Comment: Hi @Dom the original question is about `]m` and that was actually also my motivation for the plugin.  My answer mention `]m`. I'm willing to change my answer but I'll be glad if you could give me some hints.

Comment: Currently I use the repmo plugin , but might try yours one day :) Are they compatible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what compatible means in this context. Feel free to tell me more. If it works fine for you with [repmo](https://github.com/Houl/repmo-vim) maybe I should give it another try ;-)

Comment: I think @Dom’s point is that this answer should contain some specific address of the question. For example: « to repeat ]m after installing the plugin, just press ; », and so forth. The answer reads a bit more like an ad than a « here’s the solution to your problem »

Comment: @eyalkarni I understand the [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18173/23502) addressed your problem. Maybe could you accept it. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: I already accepted it.

Comment: Sorry my mistake with the new css I don't see the colors correctly :-|. I'll get used to it :-)

Comment: @eyalkarni I have been asked to document [remotions](https://github.com/vds2212/vim-remotions) and in particular the difference with [repmo](https://github.com/Houl/repmo-vim). Are you able to use repmo to remap `]m` for file type specific motion (e.g. for `python` `filetype` or even better for `python` `filetype` with [pythonsense](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-pythonsense) plugin)? If you tell me yes I'll post a question about that ;-)

Comment: It indeed doesnt work it seems. `[d ` does for example (diagnostics).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 0):

After a long time it didn't really work I returned to that, slightly improving the answer by @Hotschke.

Now, in addition to what he said, for the maps that I defined myself, I first define the mappings as usual, and  support for repeat is established like so (using repmo) :

```
nmap [a :ALEPrevious<CR>
nmap ]a :ALENext<CR>
nmap ]E <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-next)
nmap [E <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-prev)
nmap ]e <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-next-error)
nmap [e <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-prev-error)
nmap [h <Plug>(GitGutterPrevHunk)
nmap ]h <Plug>(GitGutterNextHunk)

for keys in [[']E','[E'],[']a','[a'],[']e','[e'],[']h','[h']]
    call RepRemap(keys[0],keys[1])
endfor
```

Needed function:

```
"Remaps repeat pairs
function! RepRemap(mapA,mapB)
let varA=maparg(a:mapA,'n')
let varB=maparg(a:mapB,'n')
execute "nmap <expr> " . a:mapA . " repmo#Key('".varA ."', '". varB. "')"
execute "nmap <expr> " . a:mapB . " repmo#Key('".varB ."', '". varA. "')"
endfunction
```

Possibly using map and sunmap is better.