# Undo an 'f' movement (or in general, any movement that Ctrl-O doesn't undo)

Tags: movement

I just accidentally did `f]`, how do I return the cursor to where it previously was?

Ctrl-O doesn't work of course because `f` is not regarded as a jump.

`,` doesn't work because I wasn't on a `]` previously.

Comment: I do believe you can remap it, and save the lastpos register to allow for ctrlO. I don't know if recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

But `f` only works in the current line, so you must be near anyway. This also true in general: if motion doesn't appear in the jumplist then it is probably an intra-line motion.

Comment: "you must be near anyway" so what's the fastest most brainless way I can make it back?

Comment: @theonlygusti `bbbb`...

Answer (score 1):

Use the plugin `Houl/repmo`, to extend these abilities by providing pairs of forward and reversed(backward) motions. Like `[s`, `]s`. It usually overrides the normal keys for repeating motion  `;`, `,`.

Notice that you can't exactly undo `f]`, but it does `F]`, which mostly is good enough.  It is better in the example I gave (next/prev spelling error).

Comment: I don't understand its readme, so I would really appreciate a quick setup guide in this answer that helps in regards to this question

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18162/repeat-complicated-motions/18173#18173

Comment: You may ask me in chat additional questions.