# Pressing CTRL-U combination gives invalid arguments for function timer_stop?

Tags: key-bindings

I am not precisely able to reproduce the exact conditions under which this occurs, but sometimes, when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, I get the errors below. I cannot even exit vim with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or suspend. I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening, and would appreciate any help, thank you!

[image]

Comment: It will be hard to help you: does it append when you press `<C-u>` in normal mode or in insert mode? Have you tried [debugging your vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) ? Have you tried [debugging the mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841)? I think this is a mapping calling a function which fails because neither [`:h CTRL-U`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/scroll.txt.html#CTRL-U) nor [`:h i_CTRL-U`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-U) should call something involving a timer.

Comment: what plugins are you using? Anything involving a timer? Try to grep for `s:timer_id` inside your runtime directory.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt , I am using [this](https://github.com/amix/vimrc), and it does have `s:timer_id` somewhere in there.

Comment: Well, that is a collection of vimrc together with several plugins. A short grep, showed, that at least the plugins `comfortable_motion`, `ale` and `vim-go` make use of a `s:timer_id` variable. So the question would be when does that happen and what plugin is involved. Try to see if there are updates to those plugins available and open an issue there.

Comment: What Vim version are you using? I guess the problem comes from [here](https://github.com/amix/vimrc/blob/master/sources_non_forked/comfortable-motion.vim/autoload/comfortable_motion.vim#L77). Note, also the corresponding issue [here](https://github.com/amix/vimrc/issues/472) and in the upstream repository [here](https://github.com/yuttie/comfortable-motion.vim/issues/26)

Comment: Note that there is also [this issue](https://github.com/amix/vimrc/issues/447). FWIW @sarpu this is because of this kind of problem that these distributions of vimrc are usually not a good idea for beginners: It looks easier to set up but once something goes wrong it is much more difficult to debug because you don't really know what is in your conf and how it works. Usually starting from scratch with a fresh config and adding the plugins you need one at the time is a better way to learn and to become efficient with vim.

Comment: @statox thank you, that's what I ended up doing in the end.