# How to use filename expansion in a mapping

Tags: key-bindings

I have this shorcut in my vimrc that I use all the time (admittedly, I just copied it over from the web):

```
" bind K to grep word under cursor
nnoremap K :grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:cw<CR>
```

This works excellent, it displays the matched keywards in the window below in my vim session:

[image]

This is great, but I would like to create another keyboard shortcut that only searches for the keyword under the cursor for the *current file only*.

I searched how to do that online and found this command:

```
:vim /pattern/ % | cw
```

This works fine if I type it out manually on vim, but I'm trying to create a keyboard shortcut for it using [this tutorial](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)):

```
" bind L to grep word under cursor for current file only
nnoremap L :vim <C-R><C-W>% |<CR>:cw<CR>
```

This isn't working, it's giving me a syntax error. My question is: how can I add the `%` option to the above vim command to the keyboard map?

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/10604

Answer (score 1):

I got it! Just by playing around, I got this to work:

```
" bind L to grep word under cursor for current file only
nnoremap L :vim <C-R><C-W> %<CR>:cw<CR>
```

Comment: As you noticed, the space between the pattern and percent is necessary for filename expansion. In the link i posted, there is an explanation for why the bar gave you trouble.