# Remapping motion keys

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, cursor-motions

I recently found the awesome plugin named [CamelCaseMotion](https://github.com/bkad/CamelCaseMotion/) which is awesome. I used their suggested mappings in my .vimrc for the plugin like this:

```
map <silent> w <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_w
sunmap w
omap <silent> iw <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_iw
xmap <silent> iw <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_iw
```

to map w but also b, e, ge to their respective functions. The problem is now that I want to map W, B, E to work like w, b, e worked before and <leader>w, <leader>b, <leader>e to work like W, B, E. Also I want to remap gE and g<leader>e in normal mode using the same rules above. This is where my vimscript-fu and google-fu failed me. I can't use `map <silent> W w` because I will override w, and I can't find the function to which w is mapped originally/natively by vim. Can someone help please? Also you please explain how can I find mappings for native vim keys in the future?

Edit:
:map does not help me. It does not show the native mappings for w or W motion.

```
:verbose map W
No mapping found
```

Comment: Hi. Please take a look at the answers on the page linked in the previous comment. Sounds like you are having problems with mapping to mapped commands. That page will help.

Comment: :map does not have the native vim mappings for w and W. I have searched, believe me.

Comment: @RevanDarth To map the native vim keys, e.g `w`, you can use `:normal! w<CR>`. Also consider using `nnoremap` familly instead of `nmap` which can go recursive.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. That's why I linked that page. (And take note of the second thing perelo said.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint @pereleo, but if I use noremap with CamelCaseMotion_w  the function ceases to work. I guess the developer of the plugin intended to use map.

Comment: `:nnoremap W w`

Comment: @b-layer Now I understand what you meant. noremap W w worked! It was not overriden. Thanks a million!

Comment: I'm unsure what to do form here. Would you like to wirte an answer so I can mark it as correct? Should I just delete my question because it's silly?

Comment: No worries. It's not silly. We all occasionally don't see things that are in front of us. My preference is to mark it as duplicate (which I did...though someone posted an answer despite that) since there are at least a few existing answers on the site that would cover the topic. Whatever the case there's nothing you need to do. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply use **non-recursive** mappings, which allow you to access the original command under the keys, regardless of them having been mapped to something else.

For example, for `w`, `W` and `<leader>w`:

```
map <silent> w <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_w
noremap W w
noremap <leader>w W
```

(And possibly use the `sunmap`s that you had as well.)

The first one can't use a non-recursive mapping, because `<Plug>` is a "virtual" keystroke and you're actually invoking a mapping, so you need it to be recursive. But that's fine. It's an exception and one of the few cases where you want a non-recursive mapping.

For most other cases, you will almost always want a non-recursive mapping. Use non-recursive mappings by default, unless you really know you need a recursive one.

For more details and a great discussion on them, see ["Nonrecursive Mappings"](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html#nonrecursive-mapping) on "Learn Vimscript the Hard Way", which demonstrates why they're important and why you always want to use them.

Also see the excellent answer to ["How to debug a mapping?"](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-debug-a-mapping), which has many pointers on how you can learn to debug this by yourself. (In fact, the answer to your particular question, using non-recursive mappings, is listed there under best practices.)

Comment: I marked the question as a duplicate some time ago. That's why I put the answer (same as you have here) in comments. Generally I don't think it's a good practice to write an answer while duplicate disposition is still up in the air. (I would have answered early on if it were otherwise.) Sloooow down, man.

Comment: @BLayer Ah sorry, didn't notice that, didn't really look at the comments before I started typing the answer... Will keep an eye on it going forward.

Comment: hi filbranden, thank you for explaining things in detail and for the awesome references. Given that my question really was a duplicate I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @RevanDarth Basically everything in this answer is in the page I linked including that book chapter.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Good call! Added a reference to that answer. I agree that, even though the information *is* there, for the OP to find it there would have been quite daunting. (If they knew what they were after, they would probably have found it already.) I also don't see much harm in having an answer *and* marking the question as a duplicate, since that usually also counts as a "see also" in cases where a potential asker's problem is similar but not exactly the same.