# navigating dictionary completion

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, dictionary

In my vimrc I have the following mappings:

```
set completeopt=longest,menuone,preview
inoremap <C-h>    <C-n> 
inoremap <C-k>    <C-p>
inoremap <Leader>k <C-x><C-k>
```

I want to be able to navigate up and down in the dictionary completion list I get with `<Leader>k` by using `<C-h>` and `<C-k>`. However, both move down in the list, contrary to the behaviour I'd expect as I have them mapped to `<C-n>` and `<c-p>`. Any idea why this doesn't work? The keybindings behave the way they should when I access keyword completion, so I'm not sure what I might have done wrong.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Not that it should affect things, but can you [edit] and add your `<Leader>` for completeness?

Comment: Welcome! I would advise that you read [How do I debug a mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) and report to us what issues you found following the answer.

Comment: @myc3lium is the issue solved and how?