# F10 is not yet available to Vim via gnome-terminal

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

I'm using `gnome-terminal` for first time (after using xterm for many years).

And the one keystroke that no longer works within gnome-terminal from my Vim application is Function Key F10.

I've turned off Menu Accelerator (F10) option in the Gnome-Terminal's `Edit`->`Preferences`, then `General` tab:

[image: Gnome-Terminal Preferences->General]

But my remapped Vim F10 key is still not firing.

Any intermediate troubleshooting steps that I can try?

:-/

Comment: Either your problem lies in your vim config and [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) should help you to pinpoint the problem, or it is indeed an issue with your terminal emulator and then your question should be asked on [Unix&Linux.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: FWIW this is working fine for me (in Vim 8.1 on Ubuntu 20.04, using vim-xdebug which makes use of F10). Didn't even have to restart the terminal.