# Is it possible to map control forward-slash with vim

Tags: key-bindings

I'm wondering if it is possible to map control + forward-slash in vim. The mapping would be for normal mode if that makes a difference.

I have tried `<c-/>` but that didn't work.

I also tried looking at the `:help keycodes` docs but was unable to understand if it was possible.

Comment: it is often `<c-_>`

Comment: You can in xterm, with a recent Vim.  You may need to specify the shift modifier, so try `<c-s-/>` in addition to `<c-/>`.

Comment: @Mass I added your comment as a Community Wiki answer, as I could reproduce it. Not sure if this is the best conduct here, if not please apologize me. I could not find any reference to that, if you have it, please add it.

Comment: @Quasímodo seems fine to me; I agree it would be great to have more detail, but answers belong in answers, not comments.

Comment: Related question on different sites: [\[SOLVED\] Vim strange behaviour of CTRL-/ mapping under xterm / Applications & Desktop Environments / Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=259737), [Under xterm, <CTRL-_> stops working after pressing another control character · Issue #7108 · vim/vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7108)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `<C-_>`. For example, to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> to `:help`,

```
noremap <C-_> :help<CR>
```

---

From `:help :map-special-keys`,

> There are three ways to map a special key:
>
> 1. The Vi-compatible method: Map the key code.  Often this is a sequence that
>    starts with <Esc>.  To enter a mapping like this you type ":map " and then
>    you have to type CTRL-V before hitting the function key. (...)

If I try `:map` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>, I get the `^_` symbol, indicating that the corresponding map is `<C-_>`. If you get some other sequence, map that instead.