# Why is my vim key mapping not working?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

The map `noremap <silent> <C-i> :call CocActionAsync('doHover')<cr>` doesnot work but doing same mapping for other key combination like `<leader>h`  works.
[image]

What might be the problem?

Comment: `<c-i>` is tab, and you likely have something else overriding the tab mapping.  What does `:verbose nmap <tab>` show?

Comment: Although `:verbose nmap <tab>` doesnot show anything, it might be because tab is used for code completion by `coc`.
<C-_> is also not working. Do you know of any such reason.

Comment: I don't think `<c-_>` can be mapped. I tried and it doesn't work for me, no matter what I map it to.

Comment: Actually `<C-_>` mapping is for `ctrl+ forwardslash` .https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26611/is-it-possible-to-map-control-forward-slash-with-vim

Comment: What version of Vim are you using? I just discovered that I did, in fact, have `<C-_>` mapped and it stopped working.