# Unable to map C-/ in visual mode with Neovim and kitty

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, terminal, kitty-terminal

I am unable to map `<C-/>` in Neovim. In particular, it does not work for visual mode. I have created the mappings below:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('i', '<C-/>', '<Esc>:Commentary<CR>')    
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-/>', 'gcc')    
vim.keymap.set('v', '<C-/>', 'gc')
```

Using vim I have the mapping below, which works fine:

```
imap <C-_> <Esc>:Commentary<CR>
nmap <C-_> gcc
vmap <C-_> gc
```

But `<C-_>` also does not work for Neovim. I can also confirm using `<C-V> <C-/>` that Neovim indeed sees `<C-/>` and not `<C-_>` like vim.

I am aware of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26611/is-it-possible-to-map-control-forward-slash-with-vim), but it seems Neovim has different behavior from vim.

Edit: I found out it is a problem with Kitty, other terminals do send <C-_>

Answer (score 1):

Setting `remap = true` solves the issue.

```lua
vim.keymap.set('i', '<C-/>', '<Esc>:Commentary<CR>')
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-/>', 'gcc', { remap = true })
vim.keymap.set('v', '<C-/>', 'gc',  { remap = true })
```

Comment: I tried to map gcc to another command and remap=true got it working, but I'm not clear why, can you expand?