# How to re-source a file based on filetype

Tags: vimrc

I am trying to add the following mapping into my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC | filetype detect<cr>
```

This works in command mode, however, in the mapping I get:

> E475: Invalid argument: detect

Why does it throw that error? What would be the proper way to get around it?

Comment: You need to escape the bar: `\|` or use `<bar>` instead..per `:h :bar`. But this shouldn't work from the command line either. Unescaped bar is always illegal "as an argument".

Comment: @BLayer to source? It should work fine if typed literally, unless source doesnt allow bar separator (a very few commands dont)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Quoted part is from help...an arg to `nnoremap` is what I was thinking. I.e. unescaped bar doesn't ever work on the rhs of mappings, I believe.

Comment: A good resource for your future mappings issues: [How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841)