# How to turn this piped bash command into a vim map?

Tags: shell

I have a bash command that will align text into a tabular form. If I have input such as this:

```
A | B | C
Alpha | Beta | Gamma
12 | 34.56 | 78.9
```

I can run `cat test.txt | sed -e 's/|/'$'\001''|/g' | column -t -s $'\001'` to get:

```
A       | B       | C
Alpha   | Beta    | Gamma
12      | 34.56   | 78.9
```

The `\001` is a delimiter I use with `column` since I want to retain the `|` in the text.

I can run this command inside vim by first visually selecting lines and then `:'<,'>!sed ...` with command exactly as above, without the `cat`.

I want to turn this into a vim map so that I can visually highlight a bunch of rows, or use text objects, and do the same alignment. Unfortunately, the following:

```
vnoremap <leader>t :'<,'>!sed -e 's/|/'$'\001''|/g' | column -t -s $'\001'
```

gives me the error `E486: Pattern not found: '$'\001''|` for the first `$'\001'`.

How to resolve this?

Comment: not solving your problem, but you can consider making this into a bash script

Comment: wow, I'm stoked to learn that this combination of visually-selected text + external command to update it is even possible!!!

Comment: @alex `:help filter` :) For the OP, probably `:help map-bar` and [How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/10604) (sorry, wrong link earlier)

Comment: fwiw... vimwiki has a neat table feature that you might find handy

Comment: `The \001 is a delimiter` What's wrong with `column -t -s\| -o\|` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue that needs fixing here is that the `|` character is special here, it is used as a separator for Ex commands and is not passed verbatim to your mapping.

In order to fix it, you need to either use `<Bar>` or `\|` here.

See [`:help map-bar`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#map-bar) for more details.

Additionally, you'll probably want to add a `<CR>` at the end, to actually execute the command when the mapping is activated.

Finally, you might want to use `xnoremap` here, since `vnoremap` affects both Visual and Select mode. (Select mode is not used very often, but mapping Visual mode only is typically the more correct choice here.)

Putting it all together:

```
xnoremap <leader>t :'<,'>!sed -e 's/<Bar>/'$'\001''<Bar>/g' <Bar> column -t -s $'\001'<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @Mass's comment suggested, you can create a `columnize.sh` file...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

sed -e 's/|/'$'\001''|/g' | column -t -s $'\001'
```

(Make it executable of course `chmod +x columnize.sh`.)

And then in `.vimrc` map it:

```
vnoremap <leader>t :!columnize.sh<CR>
```

Comment: I don't see why invoking a script would be slower than the individual commands... In both cases you're spawning a shell, then sed and column. Other than reading the script file (which is negligible), the two are essentially he same.

Comment: I tiried both ways and there was a very significant delay when the `sed | column` commands were in a separate script file.  I have no idea why.  But it I tried a few times and it was consistent.

Comment: Maybe some problem with `$PATH`? Perhaps a network directory in there, or a directory with too many entries, that is slowing down lookup? But this would affect most of any commands that you run... Does it also happen if you call `columnize.sh` with an explicit path from Vim? Such as `:!./columnize.sh<CR>` (assuming it resides on the current directory)

Comment: Nice!  Using the full path to the script works just as fast, thanks :)

Comment: Also: *"Make it writable"* the `+x` is actually **executable**, not writable... Can you fix it?