# vimtex-compiler-ss does not open quickfix

Tags: quickfix, plugin-vimtex

Due to my muscle memory(aquired from vim-latex and other code compilation, so `<F10>` is universal compiler for me), I prefer singleshot calculation. I do have given a shot to `\ll` and then just save to compile, but unfortunate my muscle memory rejects that.
So, I have created this map:

```
autocmd Filetype tex imap <buffer> <f10> <Esc>:w<CR> <plug>(vimtex-compile-ss)<CR><Esc>
```

Unfortunately, this doesnot open quickfix as `\ll` does.

Is it possible to open quickfix when there is some error using this map?

I have also tried

```
autocmd Filetype tex imap <buffer> <f10> <Esc>:w<CR> :VimtexCompileSS<CR><Esc>
```

with no change.

**Disclaimer: VimtexCompileSs or vimtex-compile-ss is a command from vimtex plugin, popular for latex use**

Comment: Can't you chain your mapping with `:cw`? Something like `inoremap <buffer> <f10> <Esc>:w<CR> <plug>(vimtex-compile-ss)<CR>:cw<CR>`? See [`:h :cw`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acw) `Open the quickfix window when there are recognized errors.  If the window is already open and there are no recognized errors, close the window.` Also you should not use an autocomand but a custom ftplugin to create your mapping and your mapping should be not recursive (`inoremap` instead of `imap`) but that's not the point of your question :)

Comment: Usually you have to `normal <Plug>...` or use `feedkeys()`. You might want `inoremap <buffer> <f10> <C-o>:write | VimtexCompileSS | cwindow<CR>`. cf. [How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/10604)