# snippets visual is not selected when there is overfull warning

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

Disclmair: this is a question about using vim to write LaTeX. I don't know if this behaviour is visible in other languages also.

I use `Ultisnips` with `honza/vim-snippets` to expand latex snippets. If there is no warning, everything works fine.

But, if there is some warning, like `overfull/underfull hbox`, then, in expanding snippets, cursor does not highlight the $VISUAL part.

To explain the things, I have made the screencast: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NJw6wBjT7-vCn08HWYWjJoUsFe7gudPO/view?usp=sharing

The snippet is defined as

```
snippet "\\?b(egin)?" "begin{} / end{}" br
\begin{${1:something}}
    ${0:${VISUAL}}
\end{$1}
endsnippet
```

ofcourse, I expect expanding `b` will highlight the `1:something`, but as you can see, this is not.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/160ItwbFdTdr8az7O9NGu6gebEnYauwcl/view?usp=sharing is my complete `.vimrc`.

Comment: Sounds like something you could report to [their issue tracker](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues) chances are that you'll find there more people with deep knowledge of the tool who will be able to give an answer. (Also some comments on your [previous question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29233/1841) would deserve an answer from you)

Comment: @statox: i haven't commented because none of that solved the problem. Got that solved by larvag in github.

Comment: It’s still good etiquette to mention that you solved your problem, and leaving an answer so that other people with the same issue can benefit from your solution is also useful.

Comment: @statox: ok...I will do that. Actually I feel it embarassing that I write my own answer and then mark it accepted. it looks like number hunger. But of course, I will follow you as more experienced here.

Comment: You should have a look at [this section of the help center](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) to convince you that this is perfectly fine and even encouraged: The end goal of this site is to provide useful information to everybody, it doesn't really matter if the information comes from you or someone else :)