# noremap in .vimrc for YouCompleteMe does not work

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode, plugin-you-complete-me

```
noremap <leader>gdf :YcmCompleter\ GoToDefinition<cr>
noremap <leader>gdc :YcmCompleter\ GoToDeClaration<cr>
noremap <leader>gi :YcmCompleter\ GoToInclude<cr>
noremap <leader>gs :YcmCompleter\ GoToSymbol<cr>
noremap <leader>gt :YcmCompleter\ GoToType<cr>
noremap <leader>gr :YcmCompleter\ GoToReferences<cr>
```

None of them works. I get this error message:

```
ValueError: Supported commands are:
GetDoc
GetType
GoTo
```

I ran `python3 install.py --clangd-completer`. The command `:YcmCompleter GoToInclude` does work in a c source file. But the keymap I set does not work. So I think it is not due to an incomplete installation.

Comment: Do you really need the `\ ` in the right hand side of your mapping? Usually you don't need to escape spaces there and that might be the cause of the issue. Also have a look at [how to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) maybe you'll find something interesting. And finally you should use mode specific map commands like `nnoremap` it will save you some troubles in the long run.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

As @statox says, I remove the `\`, then it works.