# What exactly Ctrl + Shift + Right arrow does? How can I remap it or find help on this key combination?

Tags: key-bindings, help-system

I've noticed that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Right</kbd> deletes text until some criteria are met but I can't figure out exactly what that is.

I'm also unsure how to find help when a character doesn't have a capital version, i.e. arrows. How can I use the help command in such cases?

Comment: I don't think `Ctrl+Shift+Right` is supposed to do anything by default. Either you have a mapping on this key sequence (use `:verbose map <C-S-Right>` to see the mapping and which script created it) or this is a keycode issue where your terminal emulator understands the keycode of `<C-S-Right>` as another one which happens to delete text.

Comment: As you pointed out, there is no mapping on this sequence. It could be a tmux thing. I'll dig into it!

Comment: [An answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) I wrote a few years ago which could have been useful in your situation :) I've never heard of this being an issue in tmux (and never experienced such an issue after using tmux for several years), maybe you should check on your terminal emulator first.

Comment: oh man, what a perfect resource answer! It'll definitely help me troubleshoot this problem. The problem isn't with tmux, as you pointed out. My next step is going through my alacritty configs :)

Comment: This might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34723/289772

Answer (score 1):

In doubt I always check key sequences in gvim as it avoids side effects from the terminal.

What I observe is that it does the same thing as `<c-right>` and it seems to go the beginning of the next word, as with `w`.

If when you type `:map` + <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL+Shift+Right</kbd>, it doesn't show `:map <C-S-Right>`, then you'll have to play (or struggle...) with your terminal configuration. I won't be able to help more on this topic as I gave up the fight: I've been using gvim for two 2 decades now, mainly for this reason.

You should be able to find several Q/A and resources here, on SO, and in vim mailing lists...