# Can't use <Tab> in insert mode

Tags: neovim, macos

I installed neovim on my mac and use the config I have from my Ubuntu laptop but I can't use Tab in insert mode (not indent). I press the tab and nothing happened. Everything is fine on my Ubuntu laptop, even I press tab on vim is ok too.

Here is my config: https://pastebin.com/twE6CfKk

**NVIM v0.4.4**

Comment: What's the output of `verbose imap <Tab>`?

Comment: `i  <Tab>       * <C-R>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()<CR>                                                                                                                                        
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/plugged/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim line 58
Press ENTER or type command to continue
`
is everything good?

Comment: And the problem is that pressing tab doesn't give you a tab character?

Comment: yes, it does nothing

Comment: Can't repro in vim or neovim (admittedly 0.5.0 preview compiled a couple weeks ago) on Linux Mint 20.1. Not entirely sure what magic is going on in ExpandSnippetOrJump, but it seems to be able to return a normal tab character even when the function doesn't directly at any point. Might be better to open an issue in the ultisnips repo though - this seems a lot like a bug and not intended behavior, especially with this level of inconsistency (specifically the working on Ubuntu but not on Mac bit)

Comment: As a workaround though, you can use another key for either tab (Ctrl-i is also tab, but I'm not _entirely_ sure if that gets globbed in when mapping tab -- recursive mapping is weird) or ultisnips expansion

Comment: Control-v tab might also be a workaround; [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) [How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/10604)

Comment: @Zoe thanks for your help, I think I'll be waiting for the next couple of updates to see if it gets work.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I was debug mapping of <Tab> and it's the same with my Ubuntu config. Ctrl-V Tab not work too :((.

Comment: Hi I have this issue on Mac, is any update on this issue?

Comment: @ArdiNusawan No update yet, I'm using nano instead

Answer (score 1):

I also happened to have this issue with neovim v0.8.3

Using `:verbose imap <Tab>` (as advised by @Zoe stands with Ukraine in the question comments) also led me to believe that Ultisnips was having issues with my Tab configurations.

Uninstalling it fixed it for me.

I suspect it may be some issue with the python version that Ultisnips uses behind the scenes as my Tab used to work until today.